# The program that will find the next prime number

Tags: code-golf, math, primes

## Intro:

---

You accidentally corrupted the flow of time with a device you made for fun, that turned out to be a time machine. As a result, you got pushed to the far future. You  realized that computing, processing power, and computers in general have been evolved by a huge amount, *an infinite amount to be precise*. So you grab yourself a computer with infinite memory and processing power. You have no idea how it can have infinite memory and infinite processing power, but you just accept it and return to the present.

### Challenge:

---

You heard that the person who discovered the currently largest prime `2^74,207,281 − 1` got paid $100.000. You decide to make a program that finds the next prime, since you want to get back the money you spent for the computer. You make one that takes input of a number, and finds the next prime number, either by bruteforcing or any other method.

**Clarifications:**
You have a hypothetical machine with infinite memory and processing power. Your program MUST NOT be limited (e.g.: C#'s int's can store from `-2,147,483,648` to `2,147,483,647`), well your program must be able to store, and work with any number of any size. You have infinite resources, so you shouldnt care if you would run out of memory if you allowed that.

**Example I/O:**
Input: [The currently largest discovered prime with 22,338,618 digits.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Largest_known_prime_number)
Output: Exactly the next prime

Obviously, you dont have to prove that it works, as it would take a ton of time to compute in a physical machine. But if you moved your program to a hypothetical machine with infinite processing power / memory, it should compute instantly.

---

Finding the next prime and checking if a number is a prime, are two completely different things

Comment: Does it have to specifically be the _next prime_? Lots of prime searching algorithms for large primes only search certain types of numbers and therefore sometimes miss out primes...

Comment: Yes it has to be exactly the next prime @FlipTack. Not the next mersenne prime or anything. This is why I advised bruteforcing, (due to infinite resources, it would be ideal) but any algorithm is fine, as long as it finds the next prime.

Comment: Does the program have to validate that the input is actually a prime? Or can we just get the next prime after any input?

Comment: @theonlygusti It doesnt have to validate inputs primality.

Comment: I think you should add some serious test cases.

Comment: "*Your program MUST NOT be limited*" but on the basis of the example I suspect that every single language in existence counts as limited if fit no other reason than using a finite type to address memory.

Comment: Side note: there isn't a $100,000 bounty for every new world-record prime—only a few benchmarks, like the first prime found with a million digits. See mersenne.org

Comment: Weird, there's not a single Lisp answer to this question...

Comment: How is this different from the primality test question?  Any reasonable method is just going to be a fairly simple wrapper of the original or a builtin.

Comment: How would this be tested anyway? No machines have infinite resources.

Comment: Downvoting because I don't get the point of the challenge. Is it about finding the next prime number (trivial, and it has been done before) or manipulating large numbers in the context of prime number searching? It looks like none of the answers actually adresses this latter issue (which looks like the interestingone to me) - maybe because the question is unclear

Comment: If there were a machine with infinite processing power and memory it could instantly calculate the next prime with any program that actually works. There would no point in making programs either small or efficient any more, indeed, I suspect that in such a universe computers would be so cheap that I'd have better things to do than try to recoup the cost of one. I assume this is the case in your example, where a stick of gum may cost $100,000. I'd probably just ask a nearby computer to project all the great entertainment I missed into my mind before I notice my family have all died.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is this number a prime?](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/57617/is-this-number-a-prime)

Comment: @WheatWizard No way. Finding the next prime is different.

Comment: @mbomb007 why? All of the answers except the builtin ones seen to just add an extra wrapper.

Comment: So does pretty much any question tagged with [prime].

Comment: For all the "wtf there isnt any biggest prime number"-esque edits, the title obviously meant "next **currently known** biggest prime number so your sarcasm is not valid here :)

Answer (score 24):

## Mathematica, 9 bytes

```
NextPrime
```

Comment: ... Does this actually work?

Comment: Of course, Mathematica always has a builtin

Comment: @wizzwizz4, sure, [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus-dev/mathics#S7P975daURJQlJmb@t8tvyg609ZQJ9PG1shUJ1NbWwconlfikOaQGfsfAA)

Answer (score 13):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 45 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,k=1,m=1:m%k*k>n or-~f(n,k+1,m*k*k)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#JYxNCoMwFITX9RSzERP7LElr/wS9i60KQZNIki666dXtKx2YGfgYxtjVh4T4jhn7EMcUxucrROPdYqxJQiuW3KZ26e1j6OFobjXZVjc2n8u5c/Ch@kyC@Z55yYzXPsDBOGjCkXAi1IQz4UK4Em6EO0Grn/@hmmy3BuOSKPJ6QNWBq0AOvgV/Sym3Lw)

Comment: I believe this is Wilson's Theorem in disguise. `k` is equal to the final result, `m` contains `(k-1)!^2`. Since _(k-1)! = -1_ mod k only holds when k is prime, we have _(k-1)!(k-1)! = 1_ mod k, which when multiplied by k will be k itself. You calculate the square to get rid of the only exception of (k-1)! = 0 mod k for composite k, which occurs for k = 4. Correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: This throws `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison` for `f(1000)`

Comment: @ovs The question says we have infinite memory. Therefore we can assume an infinitely high recursion depth limit, and thus not worry about `RecursionError`.

Answer (score 7):

### Python 2, <s>78</s> <s>77</s> <s>76</s> 74 bytes

```
def f(n):
 while 1:
    n+=1
    if[i for i in range(1,n)if n%i<1]==[1]:return n
```

---

-1 byte thanks to @KritixiLithos
-1 byte thanks to @FlipTack
-2 bytes thanks to @ElPedro

Comment: `n%i<1` is shorter than `n%i==0`

Comment: You don't need whitespace after that `if`.

Comment: I think you mean `<1`

Comment: I think you can use a tab instead of 2 spaces for the second level indents but I can't test at the moment.

Comment: @ElPedro is right. You can change the 2 spaces in front of `n+=1` and `if` into tabs and save 2 bytes

Comment: Sorry @ovs. I'm still predominantly Python 2 so wasn't aware of that. Will remember for next time :-)

Comment: [67 bytes](https://tio.run/##BcFBCoMwEAXQtTnF3xRm0EXNMtDDCGbqQPjKkFI8fXzvuvtxMo@xV4MJtST8D28Va0kT58@aJjdsrQlfDjsDDidi47dKXqhaovZfEBxXOLuY5LfqeAA "Python 2 – Try It Online") by using `all(..)`instead of the list comprehension.

Answer (score 7):

## Regex  (PCRE2 <sub><sup>v10.35 or later</sup></sub>), <s>80</s> 77 bytes

```
^(?=(?*(x+?)(x*$))(?!(?*(xx+)(x+$))(?=\3*(x+))(?=\4\5(x*))\6\2\3*$))\2x+|\B|$
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=hVbNbttGED4W0FOsmcTeJalUkmvDEE0Lji3ABmI7UGQ0jaUSNLmUFqGWBLmMZTe-9gF67aWXHPNA6bGv0UtnfyTRloAStrQ7O_PNz34z1J_fojytSvkfTKLo243VTPOooJ3mgTX-PngR04Rxit6dDPqd4OTqtB9cX54Pg5_PT4dn6KDxgvEorWKKDpXR6-lRI5qGBQrymzHy0cB6c3f36Xa3-uX-_sNwun83xV8rkTQPvl_8ins-7tl47vQIntsvCcG9LSWYOyBwlMAf7UoNvfxptAeKhIz2Rx2Qg8KoM3e-jN58ealB__7hX_Lcn-UiO_eD3Gl7tWBLUTA-kdGuZCwDKQ1nR2t6Rw3GBcphKQJaFFmBo4yXAqlM7Rkty3BCCfqtFHG3G4EGOjxERiyXSk55nHqooKIqOGp7j2uYch9lMXXRbZalKPOTMC0lrHJj4G46e_tjr4HgYQnCqujBhBqMwGhhjYP1rV2fnB0PDmxiDl1UsgeaJXgZ-I8LSU2fEKK8yAdnqKeTiLJKoC5aJkpkepYyQyqCLrKeJa-MLQusrBG3yLIeCTBuqjNZFqXx2Kh4ySacxijN-ER_hLy8o4WnCja7D6IwTSEMk7vZBbdpFn1CduSizxmLkR2HIoTaySLJJfJ9hOWJTbZXGMRgO87yZlrmZmYh4xgAVID5DRAhpRznpNke-y1Pp6DZgfLIt3Cva3mwcvxcf1lA2RNJaQLyChB3O4GASwVbCT-BhYKuAzGeV0Kaq8TgCpFd0MV-FopoGqhc7NVaoxW0rFLh6ivwTLO-P__YV5IkKSkcQr6QwkRMnyjY2WcaCbAyNwFNu_A_y1lKsSHF-3fDAcmj11EAwWLiGoyP_cFVMOwPLs4vj4f904W4_2HYvzyV-20Vk_k2kbTIisFbBRDQ1L7eDerT6NVS99eqEcA-FDRIimwW5KEQtOC4AJZfXr99awDqNtC6gs4FFHGx8jedG1i8hgIZLCm4gHBrvHQ38ew5gHaVshmrgzTbxKspxTQX_6tU0KgqSpbxjYrKbZIVSE2XhyVzYWKkMNaxbmTGXc094i0Yr64HTHgLyhOKjGGlsLh-uH_edlGelXCsT-A1EeOd5o5xKh_elrUFnS2_zvNul0thbwMucpS-g9oEBgZvrbD0rJXuOL3TuxvedtpjD4bNDCqBSxftzHdkYFCgEg7Hfs1-WQTmc9mDhz5ve8hxWD3jBSkfCIKgpBO8M-KQEpQOtBU_E2y9itE_v_-B4NXC4EiPEAis5k33kmzKp-xSxKx3FATNoCHU34rTsDbXSLy14DTuYQttbxsfW77pusHgahBcXl0cD0_OyBNDRb9aey0mhigq-swHhbfOmu1q-sP8NhlvmOTyeWysPjc1VlJQilf5rTe0VljuSX0i6kOYGcuBrTOBV4f-DfDX11Zzr9XSm_8A)

Takes its input in unary, as a string of `x` characters whose length represents the number. Returns its output as the number of ways the regex can match. (The rabbit emoji indicates this output method.)

This is the first -regex I've written that can be really said to compute its result before turning it into a number of possible matches. This output method allows actually directly returning the result; before adopting this output method, it was impossible for a regex to return a value greater than the input.

The regex computes \$p-n\$, where \$n\$ is the input and \$p\$ is the next prime. To do this it takes advantage of the fact that there will always be a prime in the interval \$(n,2n]\$. Once that is complete, it outputs \$p-n+n=p\$ in the form of a number of possible matches.

```
    ^                    # tail = N = input number
    (?=
        (?*              # Non-atomic lookahead (try all options until matching)
            (x+?)(x*$)   # \1 = conjectured P - N; \2 = N - \1
        )
        (?!              # Negative lookahead - assert that this cannot match
            (?*          # Non-atomic lookahead (try all options until matching)
                (xx+)    # \3 = try all numbers from 2 through N-1
                (x+$)    # \4 = N - \3; assert \3 < N
            )
            (?=          # Atomic lookahead (locks onto the first match)
                \3*(x+)  # \5 = N % \3, giving \3 instead of 0
            )
            (?=          # Atomic lookahead (locks onto the first match)
                \4       # head = \4
                \5       # head += \5
                (x*)     # \6 = tail == N - head == tool to make tail = \4 + \5
            )
            \6           # tail = tail-\6 == \4 + \5
            \2           # tail -= \2
            \3*$         # Assert tail is divisible by \3
        )
    )
    \2                   # tail = \1
    x+                   # add tail to the number of possible matches
|
    \B                   # add abs(N-1) to the number of possible matches
|
    $                    # add 1 to the number of the possible matches; this gets
                         # us a return value of 2 for N==0, instead of 0 which we
                         # would have if simply adding N instead of abs(N-1)+1
```

Molecular lookahead `(?*`...`)` is used for convenience. It would be possible to port to flavors that don't have it, but the regex would be much longer – it would still need to emulate arithmetic in the range \$[0,2n]\$, but would need to do so within just \$[0,n/4]\$ or perhaps \$[0,n/3]\$, instead of \$[0,n]\$ as this version does.

Without returning the correct value for \$0\$, this would be **72 bytes**.

## Regex  (.NET), 79 bytes

```
(?=(x)*)((?<1>x)+?)(x*$)(?<!(?=(?=\6*(x+))\5\4(?<=^\3\6*))(^x+)(x+x))|(?<1>){2}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RZBBboMwEEWv4qKR8EBBJGm7CHWJ1HVPEBIJUSdYcmxkjGKFsu0BesRehJpEUZfv/5k/X9PqMzddw6WcwLCt4Ufuduu14me6CSdaMOowQkqL18Wbw7hA6iJAjw@zV7DyJaIuRiyfyyevsn258hIi3XvVOw7x67qMw3Kcws1j8K5PrZD8M8AcLizLD9rwqm4oSCIUAaHa3uIAFQOZdK0UNkiCXBwoVGmte2UTaclyHogZVNtsN/oACopthbK7q5KDSiS/82LmOMZhzjgxMOlHZeuGdzR0YQQKb84Fh7MRlieN7uzomy3yfyaJ0v4lUihOAlDk9/uHgE9Lj0b3bedvpHXV2t7w7lYSg3EcpyxZZdkf)

Returns its output as the capture count of group `\1`.

```
                           # tail = N = input number
    (?=(x)*)               # \1.captureCount = N
    ((?<1>x)+?)(x*$)       # Assert N > 0; \2 = P - N;
                           # \1.captureCount += \2; \3 = N - \2
    (?<!                   # Right-to-left negative lookbehind
        (?=                # Atomic lookahead
            (?=            # Atomic lookahead
                \6*(x+)    # \4 = N % \6, giving \6 instead of 0
            )
            \5             # head = \5
            \4             # head += \4
            (?<=           # Right-to-left atomic lookbehind
                ^\3\6*     # Assert head-\3, that is, \5+\4-\3, is divisible by \6
            )
        )
        (^x+)              # \5 = N - \6; assert \6 < N
        (x+x)              # \6 = try all numbers from 2 through N-1
    )
|
    (?<1>){2}              # if N == 0, \1.captureCount = 2
```

Without returning a value for \$0\$, this would be **69 bytes**.

Comment: What do the emojis mean?

Comment: @Bbrk24 Except for rabbit, they're animals documented to be able to count. Bee `` is output via number of matches, because counting that is fairly lightweight to implement in most languages (bees are small). Elephant `` is output via capture count, because that is in a way kind of overkill (elephants are big), since in .NET a capture stack contains the contents of its captures, which is potentially much more information than just the number of captures. Rabbit `` is output via number of ways it can match, because rabbits multiply (breed), and this output method is great at multiplying.

Comment: @Bbrk24 The reason I use emojis for those output methods is to differentiate them from output via the length of a string. Depending on the challenge, it can be a very different, or sometimes even impossible, to output via the length of a string instead of the count of something. Trivially it's impossible to output a number larger than the input without using a counting-style output, but also there are ones like [totient function in ECMAScript](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/180255/17216) where it's much more complicated and interesting to output via string length than some type of count.

Comment: Interesting, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 2 bytes

```
Æn
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@3@4Le////9mAA)

This implicitly takes input z and, according to the manual, generate the closest prime strictly greater than z.

Answer (score 4):

## [Oasis](https://github.com/Adriandmen/Oasis), 2 bytes

Run with the **`-n`** flag.

Code:

```
p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/oasis#@1/w//9/3bz/5gA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + coreutils, 52 bytes

```bash
for((n=$1,n++;`factor $n|wc -w`-2;n++)){ :;};echo $n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#@5@WX6ShkWerYqiTp61tnZCWmFySX6SgkldTnqygW56ga2QNFNfUrFawsq61Tk3OyAfK/f//39wYAA)

The documentation for bash and factor do not specify a maximum integer value they can handle (although, in practice, each implementation does have a maximum integer value).  Presumably, in the GNU of the future on your infinitely large machines, bash and factor will have unlimited size integers.

Comment: Actually the docs do specify for factor that if built without gnu mp only single-precision is supported.

Comment: @Dani_l Well, the man entry for bash only says: "Evaluation is done in fixed-width integers with no check for overflow, though division by 0 is trapped and flagged as an error." It doesn't specify the width. (As I recall, the stock implementations of bash on my machines use 64-bit signed integers, but I can't check right now.) As for factor, it will surely be updated: the OP's future computers with infinite resources will have factor compiled with gnu_up to get unlimited precision :).

Answer (score 3):

## Maxima, 10 bytes

```
next_prime
```

A function returns the smallest prime bigger than its argument.

Answer (score 3):

## Python with sympy, 28 bytes

```python
import sympy
sympy.nextprime
```

`sympy.nextprime` is a function which does what it says on the tin. Works for all floats.

[**repl.it**](https://repl.it/FYgk)

---

## Python, <s>66</s> 59 bytes

-4 bytes thanks to Lynn (use `-~`)
-3 bytes thanks to FlipTack (use `and` and `or`, allowing `...==1` to be switched to a `...-1` condition.)

```python
f=lambda n:sum(-~n%-~i<1for i in range(n))-1and f(n+1)or-~n
```

[**repl.it**](https://repl.it/FYgm/1)

A recursive function that counts up from `n` until a prime is found by testing that only one number exists up to `n-1` that divides it (i.e. 1). Works for all integers, raises an error for floats.

Works on 2.7.8 and 3.5.2, does not work on 3.3.3 (syntax error due to lack of space between `==1` and `else`)

Comment: `(n+1)%(i+1)` is `-~n%-~i`, I think.

Comment: It is, thanks... I was trying to do a  shorter one using Wilson's theorem.

Comment: Does short circuiting `and`/`or` work, such as `f=lambda n:sum(-~n%-~i<1for i in range(n))==1and-~n or f(n+1)`?

Comment: In fact, that ^ can be golfed to `f=lambda n:sum(-~n%-~i<1for i in range(n))-1and f(n+1)or-~n`

Comment: @FlipTack I originally avoided them so it could pass through zero, but it'll work - that's a three byte save!

Comment: `f=` is unnecessary. Just like the first solution, omitting `f=` will make the program return a function which does what you need.

Comment: @Makonede Full programs cannot "return a function" they only return an exit code. Regardless the second function here is recursive and so the `f(n+1)` will need `f` to be a reference to this same function and so `f=` is necessary (even if full-programs could somehow do what you suggest).

Comment: Ah good point. However, an issue here is that the one using `sympy` does in fact return a callable function, which, when run, will do what is expected. I think you're contradicting yourself here.

Comment: @Makonede No contradiction, the requirements of a function on this site are just that it be reusable later in code and that it fulfils the specification in the question. Both of these happen to be named functions, the second only needs to be named so it can reference itself.

Answer (score 3):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 2 bytes

```
<ṗ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brachylog2#@2/zcOf0///N/0cBAA)

#### Explanation

```
(?) <   (.)      Input < Output
      ṗ (.)      Output is prime
                 (Implicit labelization of the Output at the end of the predicate)
```

Answer (score 2):

### Pyke, <s>8</s> 7 bytes

```
~p#Q>)h
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=%7Ep%23Q%3E%29h&input=5)

#### 4 bytes, noncompeting

(Interpreter updated since challenge posted)

```
~p<h
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=%7Ep%3Ch&input=5)

```
~p   -   primes_iterator()
  <  -  filter(^, input() < i)
   h - ^[0]
```

Comment: Why's the second noncompeting? I don't understand enough.

Comment: @theonlygusti: Typically, the only legitimate reason to mark a submission noncompeting here (as opposed to not submitting it at all) is because you fixed a bug or added a feature in the language the program's written in, and that helped you with the challenge. (I tend to write it as "language postdates challenge" to be more clear.)

Comment: @theonlygusti clarified

Answer (score 2):

## Python, <s>114</s> 83 bytes

```
def g(b):
 while 1:
  b+=1
  for i in range(2,b):
   if b%i<1:break
  else:return b
```

Without builtins, if there are any.

-30 by removing whitespace and -1 by changing `b%i==0` to `b%i<1`

Comment: This won't find the next prime if you put in `1`

Comment: It now assumes that b>2

Comment: You can't just make up your own rules... you need to follow the challenge specification. Nowhere does it say that you can assume the bounds of the input.

Comment: Even with that assumption, this fails for all even valued inputs.

Comment: I'm an idiot, i misread it. Fixed it. @FlipTack

Comment: you can use spaces for single indents and tabs for double indents to save bytes

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 25 bytes

```perl6
{first *.is-prime,$_^..*}
```

#### How it works

```perl6
{                       }  # A lambda.
                  $_ ..*   # Range from the lambda argument to infinity,
                    ^      # not including the start point.
 first           ,         # Iterate the range and return the first number which
       *.is-prime          # is prime.
```

---

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 32 bytes

```perl6
{first {all $_ X%2..^$_},$_^..*}
```

With inefficient custom primality testing.

#### How it works

Outer structure is the same as above, but the predicate passed to `first` (to decide if a given number is prime), is now:

```perl6
{               }  # A lambda.
     $_            # Lambda argument (number to be tested).
          2..^$_   # Range from 2 to the argument, excluding the end-point.
        X          # Cartesian product of the two,
         %         # with the modulo operator applied to each pair.
 all               # Return True if all the modulo results are truthy (i.e. non-0).
```

Comment: I was hoping to get something shorter with [Perl 5](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/108695/2771) but it's hard to beat a built-in `.is-prime` ;)

Answer (score 2):

## Lua, 876 Bytes

```lua
function I(a)a.s=a.s:gsub("(%d)(9*)$",function(n,k)return tostring(tonumber(n)+1)..("0"):rep(#k)end)end function D(a)a.s=a.s:gsub("(%d)(0*)$",function(n,k)return tostring(tonumber(n)-1)..("9"):rep(#k)end):gsub("^0+(%d)","%1")end function m(a,b)local A=K(a)local B=K(b)while V(0,B)do D(A)D(B)end return A end function M(a,b)local A=K(a)local B=K(b)while V(m(B,1),A)do A=m(A,B)end return A end function l(n)return#n.s end function p(a)local A=K(a)local i=K(2)while V(i,A)do if V(M(A,i),1)then return false end I(i)end return true end function V(b,a)A=K(a)B=K(b)if l(A)>l(B)then return true end if l(B)>l(A)then return false end for i=1,l(A)do c=A.s:sub(i,i)j=B.s:sub(i,i)if c>j then return true elseif c<j then return false end end return false end function K(n)if(type(n)=='table')then return{s=n.s}end return{s=tostring(n)}end P=K(io.read("*n"))repeat I(P)until p(P)print(P.s)
```

Lua, unlike some other languages, does have a Maximum Integer Size. Once a number gets larger than 2<sup>32</sup>, things stop working correctly, and Lua starts trying to make estimates instead of exact values.

As such, I had to implement a new method of storing numbers, in particular, I've stored them as Base10 strings, because Lua doesn't have a size limit on Strings, other than the size of the memory.

I feel this answer is much more to the Spirit of the question, as it has to itself implement arbitrary precision integers, as well as a prime test.

### Explained

```lua
-- String Math
_num = {}

_num.__index = _num

-- Increase a by one.
-- This works by grabbing ([0-9])999...$ from the string.
-- Then, increases the first digit in that match, and changes all the nines to zero.
-- "13", only the "3" is matched, and it increases to 1.
-- "19", firstly the 1 is turned to a 2, and then the 9 is changed to a 0.
-- "9" however, the 9 is the last digit matched, so it changes to "10"
function _num.inc(a)
    a.str = a.str:gsub("(%d)(9*)$",function(num,nines)
            return tostring(tonumber(num)+1)..("0"):rep(#nines)
        end)
end


-- Decrease a by one
-- Much like inc, however, uses ([0-9])0...$ instead.
-- Decrements ([0-9]) by one and sets 0... to 9...
-- "13" only the "3" is matched, and it decreases by one.
-- "10", the "1" is matched by the ([0-9]), and the 0 is matched by the 0..., which gives 09, which is clipped to 9.
function _num.dec(a)
    a.str = a.str:gsub("(%d)(0*)$",function(num,zeros)
        return tostring(tonumber(num)-1)..("9"):rep(#zeros)
    end)         :gsub("^0+(%d)","%1")
end

-- Adds a and b
-- Makes A and B, so that the original values aren't modified.
-- B is then decremented until it hits 0, and A is incremented.
-- A is then returned.
function _num.__add(a,b)
    local A = str_num(a)
    local B = str_num(b)
    while B > 0 do
        A:inc()
        B:dec()
    end
    return A
end

-- Subs b from a
-- Works just like Addition, yet Dec's A instead of Incs.
function _num.__sub(a,b)
    local A = str_num(a)
    local B = str_num(b)
    while B > 0 do
        A:dec()
        B:dec()
    end
    return A
end

-- A % B
-- Makes A and B from a and b
-- Constantly subtracts B from A until A is less than B
function _num.__mod(a,b)
    local A = str_num(a)
    local B = str_num(b)
    while A >= B do
        A = A - B
    end
    return A
end

-- #a
-- Useful for golfiness
function _num.__len(n)
    return #n.str
end

-- Primacy Testing
-- Generates A from a and i from 2.
-- Whilst i is less than A, i is incremented by one, and if A % i == 0, then it's not a prime, and we return false.
-- Once that finishes, we return true.
function _num.isprime(a)
    local A = str_num(a)
    local i = str_num(2)
    while i < A do
        if A%i < 1 then
            return false
        end
        i:inc()
    end
    return true
end

-- b < a
-- A and B are generated from a and b
-- Fristly, if the length of A and B aren't equal, then that result is output.
-- Otherwise, each character is searched from left to right, the moment they are unequal, the difference is output.
-- If all the characters match, then it's equal. Return false.
function _num.__lt(b,a)
    A=str_num(a)
    B=str_num(b)
    if #A > #B then
        return true
    end
    if #B > #A then
        return false
    end
    for i=1, #A.str do
        As = A.str:sub(i,i)
        Bs = B.str:sub(i,i)
        if As > Bs then
            return true
        elseif As < Bs then
            return false
        end
    end
    return false
end


-- b <= a
-- Same as b < a, but returns true on equality.
function _num.__le(b,a)
    A=str_num(a)
    B=str_num(b)
    if #A > #B then
        return true
    end
    if #B > #A then
        return false
    end
    for i=1, #A.str do
        As = A.str:sub(i,i)
        Bs = B.str:sub(i,i)
        if As > Bs then
            return true
        elseif As < Bs then
            return false
        end
    end
    return true
end

-- Just straight up returns it's string component. Endlessly faster than the int equivalent, mostly because it never is anything _but_ the string form.
function _num.__tostring(a)
    return a.str
end

-- Just set up the metatable...
function str_num(n)
    if(type(n)=='table')then
        return setmetatable({str = n.str}, _num)
    end
    return setmetatable({str = tostring(n)}, _num)
end

-- Generate a new str_num from STDIN
Prime = str_num(io.read("*n"))

-- This is handy, because it will call Prime:inc() atleast once, and stop at the next prime number it finds.
-- Basically, if it weren't for all that overhead of making the math possible, that's all this would be.
repeat
    Prime:inc()
until Prime:isprime()
print(Prime)
```

Although the above uses Metatables, instead of just regular functions like the actual answer, which worked out smaller.

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 2 bytes

```
∆Ṗ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=1#WyIiLCIiLCLiiIbhuZYiLCIiLCI1Il0=)

Here for completeness. Like answers in many other golfing langs, `∆Ṗ` is simply a builtin for "next prime greater than n". It uses `sympy.nextprime` from Python's `sympy` library to do this

Answer (score 1):

## J, 4 bytes

```
4&p:
```

Simple built in for next prime.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>16</s> 13 bytes (Emigna @ -3 bytes)

```
2•7£?ÿ•o[>Dp#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@2/0qGGR@aHF9of3Axn5h1ZGH1pnd2hlgfKhdf//R1ta6uga6Zga65jomJnrmJrqGAGZxrEA)

```
2•7£?ÿ•o        # Push current largest prime.
        [   #    # Until true..
         >Dp    # Increment by 1, store, check primality.
                # After infinite loop, implicitly return next prime.
```

Comment: Wouldn't `[>Dp#` work?

Comment: You can still cut 8 more bytes as the program should take a prime as input and output the next prime.

Comment: @Emigna then this question is a duplicate.

Comment: That is probable yes.

Answer (score 1):

## Java 7, <s>373</s> <s>343</s> <s>334</s> <s>303</s> 268 bytes

```
import java.math.*;class M{public static void main(String[]a){BigInteger n,i,o,r=new BigInteger(a[0]);for(r=r.add(o=r.ONE);;r=r.add(o)){for(n=r,i=o.add(o);i.compareTo(n)<0;n=n.mod(i).compareTo(o)<0?r.ZERO:n,i=i.add(o));if(n.compareTo(o)>0)break;}System.out.print(r);}}
```

-75 bytes thanks *@Poke*

**Ungolfed:**

```
import java.math.*;
class M{
  public static void main(String[] a){
    BigInteger n,
               i,
               o,
               r = new BigInteger(a[0]);
    for(r = r.add(o = r.ONE); ; r = r.add(o)){
      for(n = r, i = o.add(o); i.compareTo(n) < 0; n = n.mod(i).compareTo(o)< 0
                                                        ? r.ZERO
                                                        : n,
                                                   i = i.add(o));
      if(n.compareTo(o) > 0){
        break;
      }
    }
    System.out.print(r);
  }
}
```

[Try it here.](https://ideone.com/mhrhxP)

**Some example input/outputs:**

```
7 -> 11
1609 -> 1613
104723 -> 104729
```

Comment: @Poke I've golfed another 31 bytes by adding `static` for the field and method `p`, but removing method `c` and `p`'s parameter.

Answer (score 1):

### Perl, 30 bytes (29 +1 for `-p`):

```
(1x++$_)=~/^(11+?)\1+$/&&redo
```

**Usage**

Input the number after pressing return (input 12345 in example below, outputs 12347):

```
$ perl -pe '(1x++$_)=~/^(11+?)\1+$/&&redo'
12345
12347
```

**How it works**

- Define a string of `1`'s that has length `++$_`, where `$_` is initially the input value
- The regex checks to see if the string of `1`s is non-prime length (explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3329766/133939)).
- If the string length is non-prime, the check is re-evaluated for the next integer (`++$_`)
- If the string length is prime, the implicit `while` loop exits and `-p` prints the value of `$_`
- Note: there is no need to handle the edge case `"1"` of length 1 because it will never be used for values less than `1`, per the specification.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 2 bytes

```
ÅN
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f@oY97/w61@//8DAA)

```
ÅN  # full program
ÅN  # push smallest prime greater than...
    # implicit input
    # implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 5 bytes

```
fP_Th
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/Py0gPgRIGZoCAA)

---

Explanation:

```
f      # first integer greater than or equal to
    hQ # input + 1
 P_T   # which is prime
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>4</s> 3 bytes

*Edit: -1 byte thanks to Leo*

```
ḟṗ→
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//@GO@Q93Tn/UNun///@GBgaWAA)

```
ḟ     # first element that
 ṗ    # is a prime,
  →   # counting up beginning at one greater than the input
```

Comment: `ḟ` can take a number rather than a list as second argument, and count up from that https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//@GO@Q93Tn/UNun///@GBgaWAA

Comment: @Leo - Thanks!  I really should have read the manual...

Answer (score 1):

### Java, 176 Bytes

```
import java.math.*;import java.util.*;class a{public static void main(String[] args){System.out.print(new BigInteger(new Scanner(System.in).nextLine()).nextProbablePrime());}}
```

Comment: Welcome to the site and nice first answer! Be sure to check out our [Tips for golfing in Java](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/6671/tips-for-golfing-in-java)

Comment: @ChartZBelatedly thanks! that was very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 40 bits<sup>1</sup>, 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md)

```
{›:æ¬|
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=1#WyI9IiwiIiwie+KAujrDpsKsfCIsIiIsIjQ1Il0=)

Non-built-in answer, but does use a prime check built-in

### Explained

```
{›:æ¬|
{    | # While
 ›     # incrementing the top of the stack
  :æ¬  # gives a non prime number:
       #  do nothing. just run the condition actually.
```

### [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 52 bits<sup>1</sup>, 6.5 [bytes](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md)

```
{›:KḢ₃¬|
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=1#WyI9IiwiIiwie+KAujpL4bii4oKDwqx8IiwiIiwiNDUiXQ==)

Uses `KḢ₃` as a prime check (`len(factors(x)[1:] == 1`)

Answer (score 1):

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata) `-1`, 3 bytes

```
Ƥ$>
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHFZtJKuoVLsgqWlJWm6FkuOLVGxW1KclFwMFViwyMgYwgIA)

##### Explanation

```python
Ƥ$>  # Implicit input
Ƥ    # Find the first prime
  >  # which is greater than
 $   # the input integer
     # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
µƘP
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSVDMiVCNSVDNiU5OFAmZm9vdGVyPSZpbnB1dD0yMyZmbGFncz0lMkI=)

##### Explanation

```python
µƘP  # Implicit input
µƘ   # Find the next number after the input
  P  # which is a prime number
     # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

### [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), 34 bytes

```
:{a=a+1[2,a/2|~a%b=0|b=a]]~a<b|_Xa
```

Based off this [QBIC primality tester](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/105049/44874). Explanation:

```
:{a=a+1    Read 'a' from the command line, start an infinite loop 
           and at the start of each iteration increment 'a'
[2,a/2|    FOR b = 2, b <= a/2, b++
~a%b=0|    IF b cleanly divides a, we're no prime
b=a]]      so, break out of the FOR loop ( ]] = End if, NEXT )
~a<b|      If the FOR loop completed without breaking
_Xa        then quit, printing the currently tested (prime) number
           The second IF and the DO-loop are implicitly closed by QBIC.
```

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES7), 61 bytes

```
a=>{for(;a++;){for(c=0,b=2;b<a;b++)a%b||c++;if(!c)return a;}}
```

### Usage

```
f=a=>{for(;a++;){for(c=0,b=2;b<a;b++)a%b||c++;if(!c)return a;}}
f(2)
```

### Output

```
3
```

Comment: Nice, but I don't think this will work, as JavaScript itself (not the computer) will lose precision after just 2^53.

Comment: You're right, but I don't think that limit can be avoided, even if we split the number up in portions of 32 bits in an array, because eventually, the number needs to be processed as a whole. If you do have an idea on how to solve this, please let me know.

Comment: There are JS libraries for arbitrary-precision math--I even built one at some point--so I'm certain it's possible. I'll have a go the next time I'm at my computer

Comment: I did some googling, and it seems interesting. I'll have a shot at it too.

Answer (score 0):

## MATL, 3 bytes

```
_Yq
```

The function `Yq` returns the next prime of the absolute value of the input if the input is negative so we implicitly grab the input, negate it (`_`) and find the next prime using `Yq`.

[**Try it Online!**](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@x8fWfj/vzEA)

Answer (score 0):

## Haskell, <s>42</s> <s>46</s> 43 bytes

```
f n=[i|i<-[n..],all((>0).rem i)[2..i-1]]!!1
```

the usual code for brute force.

Of course this finds the next *smallest* prime number after `n`. There is no biggest prime.

Works for *n* > *0*.

*edit:* Assumes `n` is prime. Thanks to [@Laikoni](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56433/laikoni)'s advice in [the comments](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/108512/the-program-that-will-find-the-next-prime-number/108555?noredirect=1#comment264188_108555).

Comment: You can save a byte by replacing `head[...]` with `[...]!!0`. However I think one can assume that `n` is prime, so you can use `[n..]` instead of `[n+1..]` and then take the second element with `[...]!!1`.

Answer (score 0):

## Python + [primefac](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/primefac), <s>34</s> 32 bytes

Not quite as short as using `sympy` (another answer already uses that), but it's still pretty short, and it's *much* faster.

```python
import primefac as p
p.nextprime
```

[**Try it online**](https://repl.it/FZfS/1)

Input of `2**2000` completes in a couple seconds.

Answer (score 0):

## SimpleTemplate, 132 bytes

The algorithm is terrible, since I have to do my own code to check if a number is prime or not.
It proved to be horrible, but works.

```
{@setY argv.0}{@setX 1}{@whileX}{@setX}{@set+T Y,-1}{@for_ from2 toT}{@ifY is multiple_}{@incX}{@/}{@/}{@ifX}{@incY}{@/}{@/}{@echoY}
```

Receives the number as the first argument, outputting the result.

---

**Ungolfed:**

```
{@set number argv.0}
{@set remainder 1}
{@while remainder}
    {@set remainder 0}
    {@set+ tmp number, -1}
    {@for divisor from 2 to tmp}
        {@if number is multiple divisor}
            {@inc by 1 remainder}
        {@/}
    {@/}
    {@if remainder}
        {@inc by 1 number}
    {@/}
{@/}
{@echo number}
```

Any tips on how to remove that last `@if`?

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, 28+6 = 34 bytes

Uses the `-rprime` flag.

```
f=->i{i+=1;i.prime??i :f[i]}
```

Non-recursive version for 31+6=37 bytes:

```
->i{i+=1;i+=1 while i.prime?;i}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Japt, 6 bytes

```
_j}aUÄ
```

[Run it online.](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=X2p9YVXE&input=MTAwMA==)