# unRSA: solve the private key

Tags: code-golf, number-theory, restricted-memory

Given positive integer `n` and `e`, knowing that `e<n` and that `n` is the product of two different odd primes(but the primes are not directly given to you), find such a positive integer `d` smaller than `n` that, for each integer `m`, (m<sup>e</sup>)<sup>d</sup> ≡ m (mod n).

Your program should handle `n` up to 2<sup>4096</sup> in 1TB space, but not necessary reasonable time. You can assume such a `d` exist.

Sample Input: `n=53*61=3233, e=17`

Sample output: `d=413`

Note that your program will not be given the prime factor of `n`.

Shortest code in bytes win.

Comment: Is `n` given to us via its prime factors as in the sample input? May we assume `n` is odd?

Comment: @xnor Challenge edited.

Comment: (now the challenge had been clarified, there is no reason to close as unclear)

Comment: Are we guaranteed that `e>1`?

Comment: @xnor Apart from making the problem trivial, is there any other problems with it? May some algorithm only work correctly with `e>1` (except one that start brute-forcing at `2`, but I don't think that's very special)?

Comment: @user202729 No problems, it's was just a corner case for a golfed I was looking it.

Comment: For solutions that don't work for some special cases, just make note about that

Comment: `1` We requires every solutions equally, or, [bonuses in code-golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8106) are bad. `2` Because the site is based on [se], having too many poorly-received questions can cause you to be question-banned, while they are not even questions. That's a limit of [se], not PPCG. `3` (about the colliding ball challenge) Putting puzzles (solve an equation) in the challenge is often discouraged, because once the first person post their answer, otherusers can just use that approach. Not to say that puzzles are always bad, however.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 77 bytes

```python
def f(n,e):r=range(n);all(any(m-pow(m,e*d,n)for m in r)or print(d)for d in r)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcjBCoAgDADQX9lxCzvUDkHRxwhqCTplCNHXW9Tt8erdziLcu/MBAorxtOquVg6PQptNCa3cmMdaLszGD84IhaKQIQoovaoapaH71v3bA/LMbGBaqD8)

Direct translation of the requirement. `any(...)` becomes false when the smallest correct `d` is found, and `print(d)` returns `None`, making `all(...)` stop running.

## 76 bytes, if unlimited memory is allowed

```python
def f(n,e):r=range(n);all(any(m**(e*d)%n-m for m in r)or print(d)for d in r)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JchBCoAgEADAr@wl2BU7lIeg6DGCWoKusnjx9VZ0G6b2dhc2YzgfICBrT7ucYvnyyHTYlNByx6wUeuVo4jlDKAIZIoPQqyqRGzr61v07AprVGA3LRuMB)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 65 bytes

```python
n,e=input()
p=s=1
while n%~p:p+=1
while s%e:s-=p*n/~p+p
print s/e
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PcdNCoAgEAbQvadwE/RjhLoIhLlNAwkxfaQRbby6tYg2Dx7uvO7iahXDFAVnbjsFSmTVtcaNtTQFAcP/1HBII6GXqWCAwhEl6zRxXej1O/arnQ33i5Gueue90XZ@AA)

Finds a prime factor `p` of `n` to obtain the order `φ(n)=(p-1)(n/p-1)`. Then, solves the modular equation `d * e % φ(n) == 1` by counting up values `s` of the form `s = 1 + c * φ(n)` until a multiple of `e`is obtained. Since all expressions are arithmetical without exponents, only log-space is used.

The code actually uses `p` to stand for one below the prime to save bytes on initialization.

---

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 78 bytes

```python
lambda n,e:pow(e,F(F(n))-1,F(n))
F=lambda n:sum(k/n*k%n==1for k in range(n*n))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSFPJ9WqIL9cI1XHTcNNI09TU9dQB0xzudnClFgVl@ZqZOvnaWWr5tnaGqblFylkK2TmKRQl5qWnauRpAVX/LyjKzCtRSNPQyswrKC3RAIoYGxkb6ygYmgMA)

A direct expression using Dennis's [totient function implementation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/145316/20260).

Comment: Nope, only for square-free numbers.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

Thanks to *xnor* for -2 bytes! (pointing out `ÆṪ`, totient function)

```
ÆṪæi@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9w28Odqw4vy3T4//@/sZGx8X9DcwA)

Previously I used `Æf’Pæi@` at 7 bytes.

Comment: Let me check how `sympy.ntheory.factor_.factorint` and `sympy.numbers.igcdex` works...

Comment: It looks like you're factoring to compute `(p-1)(q-1)`, but would totient function `ÆṪ` be shorter and memory-efficient enough?

Comment: @xnor I searched for "euler" and can only find `ÆE`. Thanks!

Comment: Now I should check [this](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/master/sympy/ntheory/factor_.py#L1609)... | No problem, `totient` uses `factorint` internally, which uses "trial division, Pollard rho algorithm, or p-1 algorithm", all of them use polynomial memory (if I read correctly).

Comment: The Carmichael function `Æc` should also work if that's any better.

Comment: @xnor Which also uses `factorint`. There are no apparent benefit except the result is smaller.