# Multiplicity of Shared Totients

Tags: code-golf, sequence, number-theory

[Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function), \$\varphi(n)\$, counts the number of integers \$1 \le k \le n\$ such that \$\gcd(k, n) = 1\$. For example, \$\varphi(9) = 6\$ as \$1,2,4,5,7,8\$ are all coprime to \$9\$. However, \$\varphi(n)\$ is not [injective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function), meaning that there are distinct integers \$m, n\$ such that \$\varphi(m) = \varphi(n)\$. For example, \$\varphi(7) = \varphi(9) = 6\$.

The number of integers \$n\$ such that \$\varphi(n) = k\$, for each positive integer \$k\$, is given by [A014197](https://oeis.org/A014197). To clarify this, consider the table

| \$k\$ | Integers \$n\$ such that \$\varphi(n) = k\$ | How many? (aka [A014197](https://oeis.org/A014197)) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| \$1\$ | \$1, 2\$ | \$2\$ |
| \$2\$ | \$3, 4, 6\$ | \$3\$ |
| \$3\$ | \$\$ | \$0\$ |
| \$4\$ | \$5, 8, 10, 12\$ | \$4\$ |
| \$5\$ | \$\$ | \$0\$ |
| \$6\$ | \$7, 9, 14, 18\$ | \$4\$ |
| \$7\$ | \$\$ | \$0\$ |
| \$8\$ | \$15, 16, 20, 24, 30\$ | \$5\$ |
| \$9\$ | \$\$ | \$0\$ |
| \$10\$ | \$11, 22\$ | \$2\$ |

You are to implement A014197.

---

This is a standard [sequence](/questions/tagged/sequence) challenge. You may choose to do one of these three options:

- Take a positive integer \$k\$, and output the \$k\$th integer in the sequence (i.e. the number of integers \$n\$ such that \$\varphi(n) = k\$). Note that, due to this definition, you may **not** use 0 indexing.
- Take a positive integer \$k\$ and output the first \$k\$ integers in the sequence
- Output the entire sequence, in order, indefinitely

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins.

---

The first 92 elements in the sequence are

```
2,3,0,4,0,4,0,5,0,2,0,6,0,0,0,6,0,4,0,5,0,2,0,10,0,0,0,2,0,2,0,7,0,0,0,8,0,0,0,9,0,4,0,3,0,2,0,11,0,0,0,2,0,2,0,3,0,2,0,9,0,0,0,8,0,2,0,0,0,2,0,17,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,10,0,2,0,6,0,0,0,6,0,0,0,3
```

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/196643/66833)

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage), 6 bytes

```
‘²RÆṪċ
```

[Try It Online!](https://jht.hyper-neutrino.xyz/tio#WyIiLCLigJjCslLDhuG5qsSLIiwiMTAgw4figqwiLCIiLFtdXQ==)

```
‘²RÆṪċ  Main Link
‘       x + 1
 ²      (x + 1) ^ 2
  R     range
   ÆṪ   totient
     ċ  count how many times x shows up
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 86 bytes

```python
lambda i:sum(i==sum(2>math.gcd(n,k)for n in range(k))for k in range(3**i))
import math
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSHTqrg0VyPT1hZEGdnlJpZk6KUnp2jk6WRrpuUXKeQpZOYpFCXmpadqZGuCRbIRIsZaWpmamlyZuQX5RSUKIL3/QSoyESoMdSw1rbg4C4oy80o0MnXSNIDq/wMA)

The `3**i` is sufficient. It follows from [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function#Inequalities) inequality.

Comment: By borrowing the totient calculation from [this tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/152433/64121) from Lynn, you can do [73 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSHTqrg0VyPT1hZEZenrZ2tlqWbbZesapeUXKWQpZOYpFCXmpadqZGtla2qCxLIRYsZaWpmamv9BopkIUUMdc00rLs6Cosy8Eo1MnTQNkBoA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>44</s> 25 bytes

[crossed out 44 is still regular 44](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/226099/17602)

```
Ｉ№ＥＸ⊕θ²ＬΦ⊕ι⬤…·²λ∨﹪λν﹪ιν⊕θ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU7LCsJADLz7FXtcYb14EjyJIhSsivgD6za0gTTb7qO/v6Y@DoI5JJnMZBjX2eC8pVIqHnI65/4BQY/L7WIXI7asj0hJLhW7AD1wgkZYo3bcaDTq7JOufZPJ69EoXEoZ1cn3NSAnvbdRms@y1nb4Mak4HXDCBvQde4jz@zWIk0s/su7l@GXe6ATcpu5fMvwkIxlEM0U54gQ3yy3otVEkgkv4RhYZy@GDcEbvMmqUvi1lU1YTPQE) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs the `n`th term of the sequence. Edit: Saved 16 bytes by stealing @HyperNeutrino's upper bound, which then allowed a further 3 bytes of golfing. Explanation:

```
     θ                      Input `n`
    ⊕                       Incremented
   Ｘ                        Raised to power
      ²                     Literal integer `2`
  Ｅ                         Map over implicit range
          ι                 Current value
         ⊕                  Incremented
        Φ                   Filter over implicit range
            …·              Inclusive range
              ²             From literal integer `2`
               λ            To current value
           ⬤                All values satisfy
                   ν        Current value
                 ﹪          Does not divide into
                  λ         Inner value
                ∨           Logical Or
                      ν     Current value
                    ﹪       Does not divide into
                     ι      Outer value
       Ｌ                    Take the length
 №                          Count occurences of
                        θ   Input `n`
                       ⊕    Incremented
Ｉ                           Cast to string
                            Implicitly print
```

The innermost loop erroneously counts `0` as coprime, so this is adjusted for by searching for occurrences of `n+1`.

Comment: Can you use the upper bounds \$(n+1)^2\$, or \$2n^2\$?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Yeah, I'm pretty sure `n²+n+1` is an easier upper bound for the formula I had; `2n²` doesn't work for me as Charcoal uses 0-indexing but `(n+1)²` is fine.

Answer (score 3):

## Haskell, <s>61</s> 55 bytes

```
f x=sum[1|z<-[1..2*x^2],sum[1|y<-[1..z],gcd z y==1]==x]
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P02hwra4NDfasKbKRjfaUE/PSKsizihWByJWCRGritVJT05RqFKotLU1jLW1rYj9n5uYmadgq1BQlJlXoqCRm1igkKYAUmpoEKv5HwA)

-6 bytes thanks to Unrelated String

Comment: [-6 with `sum`](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P02hwra4NDfasKbKRjfaUE/PSKsizihWByJWCRGritVJT05RqFKotLU1jLW1rYj9n5uYmadgq1BQlJlXoqCRm1igkKYAUmpoEKv5HwA). [Bit embarrassed I got all the way to this before thinking of it...](https://tio.run/##FcvRCkAwFADQd19xax42IfPs@hGmbhiyLSGt5d8n5/2sdO2zMTHyh2lh0cxuudeOXmqKTpalVbkGQnxUosGjZ7wPRcslW8YJgggirTM/1NHS5gDhODd3A7d0gIb/y0qJ@AE)

Comment: That's a lot shorter, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 88 bytes

```javascript
n=>eval("for(t=0,j=n*n*3;j--;)t+=(P=k=>k--&&(C=(a,b)=>b?C(b,a%b):a<2)(j,k)+P(k))(j)==n")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcbRCoIwFADQXxlCeq9uo/Qtu0b4A75HxDQNp93JFKGvX52nY81u1s6Py6bYvfowUGCq@t3MEA3Ow0ZHaYlTTovSKlXilhE0NFE1KRXHUBMY2SJV7bWGVppDi2dzyRGsnDBrYMJ/kYgjDJ3j1c29nt0b7lrrm/fmC0WOD/0xC8BTCkZBlRiARSZOiNq6kSGRCWL4AQ)

Comment: -1 byte with `n*n*3`->`2<<n`

Answer (score 1):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 32 bytes

```
n->sum(i=1,2*n^2,eulerphi(i)==n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcgxDoAgDADArzRO1EAC7OUpJg6gTbSSKu@vLDdc35XD0a0BmYTyjtsxJZ9X2bKv46raT3aMRILWHnUCBMlDitFDV5ZvzgKhTJoTRLQf)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
>nLÕI¢
```

Port of [*@hyper-neutrino♦*'s Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/239775/52210).

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fLs/n8FTPQ4v@/zc0AgA) or [verify the first 25 terms](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W9k6upnr6TwqG2SgpK933@7PJ/DU/0OLfqv8x8A).

**Explanation:**

```python
>       # Increase the (implicit) input by 1
 n      # Square it
  L     # Pop and push a list in the range [1,(input+1)²]
   Õ    # Convert each value in this list to its Euler's Totient
    I¢  # Count how many times the input is in this list
        # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```