# Convert between graph representations

Tags: code-golf, matrix, graph-theory

### What?

Let's say I have this graph:

```
   1
    \
     \
2     3
 \   /
  \ /
   4
```

I can represent it in 2 ways:

1. A list of connected vertices. `[[1,3],[2,4],[3,4]]`
2. A boolean matrix which shows where edges are:

```
c |1 2 3 4
--|-------
1 |0 0 1 0
2 |0 0 0 1
3 |1 0 0 1
4 |0 1 1 0
----- or -----
[[0,0,1,0],[0,0,0,1],[1,0,0,1],[0,1,1,0]]
```

### Task

- Your code should take input in the form of 1 (as a vertex list) and output it as 2 (as an adjacency matrix)
- The graph is not directed (aka it is an undirected graph).
- You can also accept input which is 0-indexed. For example: `[[0,2],[1,3],[2,3]]`
- This is code golf, shortest answer wins.
- You can also output 2 different values instead of 1 and 0.

### Test cases

```
[[1,2],[3,4]] -> [[0,1,0,0],[1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1],[0,0,1,0]]
[[1,3],[2,4],[3,4]] -> [[0,0,1,0],[0,0,0,1],[1,0,0,1],[0,1,1,0]]
[[1,2],[2,3],[5,6]] -> [[0,1,0,0,0,0],[1,0,1,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,1],[0,0,0,0,1,0]]
[[1,2]] -> [[0,1],[1,0]]
[[1,2],[4,5]] -> [[0,1,0,0,0],[1,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,1],[0,0,0,1,0]]
[[4,5]] -> [[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,1],[0,0,0,1,0]]
[[4,5],[2,1]] -> [[0,1,0,0,0],[1,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,1],[0,0,0,1,0]]
```

Comment: Related: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/240705/55372 (part of that challenge may be calculating adjacency matrix).

Comment: Is the number of vertices required to be the largest number occurred in the input? May I output a even larger matrix with 0 padded? For example, is `[[1,2]] -> [[0,1,0],[1,0,0],[0,0,0]]` valid?

Comment: @tsh it is not valid as it implies that more verticies are present but not connected anywhere.

Comment: @JonathanAllan they might be present in any order.

Comment: Can we assume no self loop and no duplicated input?

Comment: @l4m2 you can..

Answer (score 10):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 6 bytes

```apl
¯⍸⊢,⌽¨
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn//9D6R707HnUt0nnUs/fQiv9pj9omPOrte9Q31dP/UVfzofXGj9omAnnBQc5AMsTDM/h/NZABVrXmUddiCDvtUccMIMsr2N/vUe/W2kMrFNSjow11jGJ1oo11TGJj1SF8YyDfCMhHFTUCi4LkTHXMkESR5U10TKF8CAsA)

When given an adjacency matrix, `⍸` gives the edge list (indices of 1's). Therefore the inverse `¯⍸` solves this challenge when we add the reverse edges to the input list.

I used Extended here for the short syntax for inverse functions and because the inverse of `⍸` doesn't require its input to be sorted.

Comment: wow this is short.

Comment: From some reason `I.inv` isn't defined in J, so it's much longer: ``(<:1:`[`]}0$~>./)@,|."1``

Answer (score 7):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>46</s> 43 bytes

*Edit: -3 bytes thanks to pajonk*

```r
function(x,m=0*diag(max(x))){m[x]=1;m|t(m)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZBNCsIwEEb3nqLgZiIjJP1xI/UiIlJTrV0klRAloJ691rTQVNN2NTMJ877HqJpX8nFW@lio7HZN68tdcl1WEgyKlK7yMitAZAYMIeQp9uaQsq14aRDkPVwFdSplDhwYhgQ5RBg3K8EyWO8CAIoMKVKCYKvtbEXWdc07IYsxZPRFhg3SQ253XR5zyGyGHLZkG5Dg5t/Z8Xbd3T@K1DsxZ/JZ6M5gkNlmzRnHmPhU@wMPVVyR/lQjSr/sad4Uu/4A)

Input is 2-column matrix with each row representing 2 connected vertices; output is matrix of `TRUE` and `FALSE` to indicate pairwise connections.

We could save 2 more bytes [for 41 bytes](https://tio.run/##hZDPCsIwDIfvPsXASwIZtPvjReaLiMjsdO7QTkaVgvjsc3aDddq5U5KWfL@PNK2o1ePc6GPZ5Ldr1l7uSuiqVmBIZkWVlyBzAwYRn3JvDhnfylCDxNd0EZpTpQoQwClCEhBT0q0E6yDcBQCMODFiSGCr7WwlPnTdO@JqDhl/kFGH9JD7XZfHHTJfIEc92QaktPl1drxdd/ePEfNO3Jl8FnowmGT2WUvGCaU@1fHAUxVXZDzVjNI3@z/vH7t9Aw) by returning a matrix of falsy (zero) and truthy (either `1` or `-1`) to indicate connections.

Comment: [-3 bytes](https://tio.run/##hZBNCsIwEEb3nqLgZiIjJP1xI/UiIlJTrV0klRAloJ691rTQVNN2NTMJ877HqJpX8nFW@lio7HZN68tdcl1WEgyKlK7yMitAZAYMIeQp9uaQsq14aRDkPVwFdSplDhwYhgQ5RBg3K8EyWO8CAIoMKVKCYKvtbEXWdc07IYsxZPRFhg3SQ253XR5zyGyGHLZkG5Dg5t/Z8Xbd3T@K1DsxZ/JZ6M5gkNlmzRnHmPhU@wMPVVyR/lQjSr/sad4Uu/4A "R – Try It Online") by using `diag`.

Comment: @pajonk - Thanks!  That's a neat trick to get an empty matrix!

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
;UŒṬ
```

A monadic Link that accepts a list of pairs of positive integers (the vertex list) and yields a list of lists of `1`s and `0`s (the adjacency matrix).

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9869OikhzvX/P//PzraUMcoVifaSMcYSJrqmMXGAgA)** Or see the [test-suite](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9869OikhzvX/D/c7m79qHG7jgOIOyNSM/L//@joaEMdo1idaGMdk9hYHQUQ1xjINQJyUQSNwIIgKVMdM4QgkqyJjimEC2bEAgA).

#### How?

```
;UŒṬ - Link: list of pairs of positive integers, V
 U   - reverse each pair in V
;    - V concatenate that
  ŒṬ - multi-dimensional array with 1s at those coordinates and 0s elsewhere
```

Answer (score 4):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/index.html), <s>38</s> 16 bytes

*Edit: -22 bytes thanks to a change-of-approach provoked by <s>goading</s> clever hint from [ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121/ovs).*

*Edit2: changed `+` to `∨` (logical OR) so that if there are any vertices connected to themselves, which would appear on the output matrix diagonal, they are still represented as `1` and not `2`; thanks to Neil for spotting this*

```
+⟜⍉⊢∊˜·↕2⥊1+⌈´∘∾
```

[Try it at BQN online REPL](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=Q2VsbHMg4oaQIOKIqOKfnOKNieKKouKIisucwrfihpUy4qWKMSvijIjCtOKImOKIvgpDZWxscyDin6ggMeKAvzMsIDLigL80LCAz4oC/NCwgMOKAvzAg4p+pCg==)

Uses zero-indexed input.

The [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/index.html) `Range` (`↕`) function has the behaviour: "if its argument is list of numbers, then it returns an array of list indices" ([here](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/doc/range.html)).
So we just use `↕` to construct an array filled with indices, check whether each index is present in the input, and then combine the result with its transpose (to fill-in the elements corresponding to the same connections the other-way-around).

```
∨⟜⍉⊢∊˜·↕2⥊1+⌈´∘∾    # full train:
                ∾   # flatten the input connections,
             ⌈´∘    # get the maximum,
           1+       # add 1 (since 0-based indexing),
         2⥊         # duplicate it,
       ·↕           # and construct an array of 0-based 2d-coordinates;
      ˜             # now, for each 2d-coordinate,
    ⊢∊              # check if it's in the input (1) or not (0);
∨                   # finally, logical-OR the result
 ⟜⍉                 # with the transpose of itself
```

Comment: Applying `↕⌈´` to the input might give you an idea for a different approach (with 0-indexing)

Comment: @ovs - thanks very much for the hint.  Much nicer now.

Comment: This outputs `2` for elements on the diagonal, which doesn't seem allowed to me?

Comment: @Neil - Thanks!  I wasn't sure that that was a possible input, but an easy fix anyway that doesn't cost any bytes.

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 14 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
Z©LãδQ.«~®ôDø~
```

The lack of builtins to check if a list is inside another list in 05AB1E is as always pretty dang annoying.. :/

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/6tBKn8OLz20J1Du0uu7QusNbXA7vqPv/PzraUMc4VifaSMcESBoDyVgA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeX/qEMrfQ4vPrclUO/Q6rpD6w5vcTm8o@6/zv/o6GhDHaNYnWhjHZPYWB0FENcYyDUCclEEjcCCIClTHTOEIJKsiY4phAtmxAIA).

**Explanation:**

```python
Z              # Push the flattened maximum of the (implicit) input
 ©             # Store it in variable `®` (without popping)
  L            # Pop and push a list in the range [1,®]
   ã           # Cartesian product to get all pairs of this list
    δ          # Apply double-vectorized with the input-pairs:
     Q         #  Check which pairs are equal
      .«       # Then reduce this list of lists by:
        ~      #  Bitwise-OR on the bits at the same positions
         ®ô    # Split this list into parts of size `®`
           D   # Duplicate this matrix of bits
            ø  # Zip/transpose; swapping rows/columns
             ~ # Bitwise-OR the bits at the same positions again
               # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://www.python.org), <s>90</s> <s>88</s> <s>87</s> 86 bytes

*thanks to @Kevin Cruijssen for pointing out my mistake*

*thanks to @ophact for saving 2 bytes*

*thanks to @loopy walt for saving 1 byte*

*thanks to @Jonathan Allan for saving 1 byte*

```
lambda a:(r:=range(max(sum(a,[]))+1)and[[[i,j]in a or[j,i]in a for j in r]for i in r]
```

The input is a list of lists (as in the example).

## <s>85</s> <s>84</s> 83 bytes

*thanks to @loopy walt for saving 1 byte*

*thanks to @Jonathan Allan for saving 1 byte*

```
lambda a:(r:=range(max(sum(a,()))+1))and[[not{(i,j),(j,i)}&a for j in r]for i in r]
```

The input is a set of tuples.

Comment: You need to check both directions, so both `[i,j]` and `[j,i]` should be in `a` - e.g. `[i,j]in a` should be `[i,j]in a or[j,i]in a` (there might be a shorter way to do this using `zip` perhaps).

Comment: You can remove the spaces between `or` and `[` and between `]` and `in`.

Comment: `max(sum(a,[]))` saves a byte

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica 12, 15 bytes

```
AdjacencyMatrix
```

lol.

Mathematica can accept lists of tuples as edges in a graph, so

```
AdjacencyMatrix@{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 1}}
```

produces

```
{{0, 1, 0, 1}, 
 {1, 0, 1, 0}, 
 {0, 1, 0, 1}, 
 {1, 0, 1, 0}}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice answer!

Comment: You don't need the `@*Graph` part. Most graph functions work directly on lists of `TwoWayRule`s, e.g. `AdjacencyMatrix@{1 <-> 2, 3 <-> 4}`.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize that the other graph functions did that too.  I don't think `TwoWayRule`s are valid input, and if you use tuples instead the function needs 1-indexing.

Comment: i.e. `AdjacencyMatrix@{0<->2,3<->4}` works but `AdjacencyMatrix@{{0,2},{3,4}}` doesn't, and same goes for `Graph`

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 24 bytes

```
≔⊕⌈Ｅθ⌈ιηＥη⭆η∨№θ⟦ιλ⟧№θ⟦λι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/9@xuDgzPU/DMy@5KDU3Na8kNUXDN7EiM7c0F0gXaBTqKMC4mZpAoKOQoWnNFVCUmVcCls/QUQguAfLSoRz/Ig3n/FKgJFBjdKaOQk4sUAtCJEdHITMWZI6m9f//0dHRBjpGsTrRhjrGQNIISMbG/tctywEA) Link is to verbose version of code. 0-indexed. Outputs the boolean matrix as a string array of `0` and `1`s for convenience. Explanation:

```
≔⊕⌈Ｅθ⌈ιηＥη
```

Calculate the size of the array.

```
⭆η∨№θ⟦ιλ⟧№θ⟦λι
```

For each cell of the array, check whether it or its transpose exists within the input list.

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.matrices`, 75 bytes

```factor
[ 1 swap dup mmax 1 + dup 0 <matrix> [ matrix-set-nths ] keep dup flip m+ ]
```

[image]

### Explanation

- Create a square zero-matrix large enough to accommodate the maximum value in the input.
- Set the (zero-indexed) input coordinates in the matrix to one.
- Add the resulting matrix to its transpose.

```
                         ! { { 0 1 } }
1                        ! { { 0 1 } } 1
swap                     ! 1 { { 0 1 } }
dup                      ! 1 { { 0 1 } } { { 0 1 } }
mmax                     ! 1 { { 0 1 } } 1
1                        ! 1 { { 0 1 } } 1 1
+                        ! 1 { { 0 1 } } 2
dup                      ! 1 { { 0 1 } } 2 2
0                        ! 1 { { 0 1 } } 2 2 0
<matrix>                 ! 1 { { 0 1 } } { { 0 0 } { 0 0 } }
[ matrix-set-nths ] keep ! { { 0 1 } { 0 0 } }
dup                      ! { { 0 1 } { 0 0 } } { { 0 1 } { 0 0 } }
flip                     ! { { 0 1 } { 0 0 } } { { 0 0 } { 1 0 } }
m+                       ! { { 0 1 } { 1 0 } }
```

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 98 bytes

```javascript
x=>[...Array(eval(`1+Math.max(${x})`))].map((_,i,t)=>t.map((_,j)=>x.some(v=>v==i+[,j]|v==j+[,i])))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rZI9T8MwEIZ3fkUGBptc3bgfLMiRWJGAgTFYxG2dkihtKsdEqSi/PVySorgFwcJ0H/Y999p6M1WpcmnSnR1ti5VuEtHUIowYY7fGqD3RlcpJzP17ZV/ZRtXk8r3@oDGlEqsdIS@QgqUitF9lhkXNymKjSSXCSojUjyCTB8wyzFJJKW1uvPgiijhMJERTmEnpjUIvigLgEECAzS52WReBHzPsS9mNTrEzwdEzQH/FHeMOgDuASQdoMXO4PlPgqHCVuGcBBD9W3KncZcOCHuyomMH82/7hD075Ln145hF3Avp9@G9Q@zv8P3TFzOhdrpaajAm7oi2wjeM1eOgXBQt0zLLYlkWuWV6sidGluHt6fGClNel2nSZ7kvQ@VAPpeeUjwKLxRhwdRYcTa970IVF5qfsLfjdqKQWvJYsF@u8T)

:(

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>66</s> 63 bytes

```hs
f x|r<-[1..maximum$id=<<x]=[[elem[i,j]x||elem[j,i]x|j<-r]|i<-r]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rZA9D4IwEIZ3fsUNDpocpMWPCUYHBze35gaMEIsUCGrCwH/HUgi2iTEOdrhe767Pe3fX5H5Li6LvM2i7JvIFDwKVtFI91UJe4ihqKRYiLVIlJObUdp3xc5TazyO/oU4Otj9XVXGqDuUDYlBJDcvBZE2l9uVTrTxPJbIcU0dY1o3UhQG8PwWQrUB4AEJwDAnFGjdECOPxfR1nyJEh0zlzG8/cyCdPx4kmxlrHQs2YSRNjrLJ/covBHUZoGANpizuLMenPvdj92DmG7OOLWy9Xb57YnXvUcfra4PbzfuwNubq26nsDM9chOtzvrF@4wx45EfyvX@pf)
Uses `True` and `False` for the output.

Answer (score 0):

## [PDL](https://metacpan.org/pod/PDL) (Perl Data Language) 81 chars (the second paragraph)

```
use PDL;
use PDL::NiceSlice;
$_ = [[1,3],[2,4],[3,4]];

$i=pdl($_)-1;
$m=zeroes("$_",$_)for$i->max+1;
$m->indexND($i->glue(1,$i(-1:0))).=1;

print $m;
```

Explanation per line:

- construct indices ndarray, turn 1-based to 0-based
- find highest index+1; make square matrix that size; `""` is to coerce to Perl scalar not ndarray as `zeroes` with ndarray first arg copies its dimensions
- `$i(-1:0)` reverses order of indices in 0th dimension, i.e. symmetrises; `glue(1,...)` adds rows; `indexND` selects the given elements; set them to 1