# Friend, or Foe?

Tags: code-golf, decision-problem

### Task

Provide two programs/functions `A` and `B` (not necessarily in the same language) with the following properties:

- Either program, when given its own source code as input, produces an accepting output.
- Either program, when given the *other* program's source code as input, produces a rejecting output.

It doesn't matter what happens when you provide either program with an input that is not `A` or `B`. Accepting or rejecting is defined as per [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/19205/115910):

- output truthy/falsy using your language's convention (swapping is allowed), or
- use two distinct, fixed values to represent true (affirmative) or false (negative) respectively.

Both programs must use the same method of output. Additionally, if you use truthy/falsy and they are swapped for one program, they must be swapped for both programs.

If you decide to write a function instead of a full program, you must do so for both programs.

### Scoring

Your score is the sum of the byte counts of both programs. This is code golf, so the lowest score wins.

Comment: Is _program_ to be taken literally? Or are functions allowed?

Comment: @Arnauld They could be functions too. I'll add that.

Answer (score 12):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage), 1 byte

###### Program A, 1 byte

```
Ṇ
```

###### Program B, 0 bytes

###### Outputs

Falsy = accepting; truthy = rejecting

- [A inputted into A](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzrb/YBIA): `0` (falsy)
- [B inputted into A](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzrb///8DAA): `1` (truthy)
- [A inputted into B](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8DwIPd7YBAA): `Ṇ` (truthy as it is a non-empty string)
- [B inputted into B](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8DwIA):   (falsy as it is an empty string)

###### Explanation

- The string `Ṇ` (program A) is truthy as it is a non-empty string
- The string   (program B) is falsy as it is an empty string
- In Jelly, an empty program just outputs exactly what was input. So program B produces a truthy output when program A is inputted, and a falsy output when it is given itself as input
- In Jelly, `Ṇ` is the logical NOT operator. It outputs a falsy output (`0`) when a truthy input is given, but a truthy output (`1`) when a falsy input is given. Therefore, it produces a falsy output when given itself as input, and a truthy output when program B is inputted

Answer (score 10):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>10</s> <s>7</s> 6 bytes

Anonymous tacit prefix functions, returning `⊣` for true and `⊢` for false.

#### A: `⊣/⊢`

`⊢` is an identity function, and returns the given source as-is

`⊣/` returns the leftmost character (lit. left-identity reduction), i.e. `⊣` when given A's source and `⊢` when given B's source.

#### B: `⊢/⊣`

`⊣` is an identity function, and returns the given source as-is

`⊢/` returns the rightmost character (lit. right-identity reduction), i.e. `⊢` when given A's source and `⊣` when given B's source.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1HXYv1HXYu4gBhIL/7v@KhtwqPevkddzY961zzq3XJovemjtomP@qYGBzkDyRAPz2AuJww1Juhq/juqQ01W5wIxwYarczkhRJ3gogA)

Comment: I like the symmetry of this solution

Answer (score 9):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 2 bytes

Program A:

```
A
```

Program B:

```
B
```

- [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P/fEYgA) Program A with Program A as input.
- [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P/f8f9/JwA) Program A with Program B as input.
- [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P/f6f9/RwA) Program B with Program A as input.
- [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P/fCYgA) Program B with Program B as input.

Explanation: Each program counts the number of `A`s or `B`s in the input respectively, which will be truthy for itself and falsy for the other program.

Answer (score 5):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), <s>6</s> 5 bytes

- -1 thanks to DLosc

Outputs 0 for truthy and 1 for falsy.

#### Program A, 2 bytes

```
+q
```

#### Program B, 3 bytes

```
1-q
```

#### Test cases

- [Program A, Input A](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P9fuxCEAQ)
- [Program A, Input B](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P9fu/D/f0PdQgA)
- [Program B, Input A](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P/fULfw/3/tQgA)
- [Program B, Input B](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P/fULcQTAAA)

#### Explanation

`+q` forces the input into an integer. `+q` evaluates to 0, and `1-q` evaluates to 1.

`1-q` subtracts the input from 1, once again forcing it into an integer. `+q` will therefore be 1, and `1-q` will therefore be 0.

Comment: @DLosc thanks, updated.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 16 + 15 = <s>49</s> <s>46</s> <s>44</s> <s>40</s> 31 bytes

[crossed out 44 is still regular 44 :(](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/239777/106959)

I don't think there's a optimal way to golf this.

`-1` for Truthy, `0` for Falsy

### Program A

```python
0
print~-input()
```

[Input A](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/34CroCgzr6RONzOvoLREQxNTBAA)

[Input B](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/34CroCgzr6RONzOvoLREQ/P/f0OICEwAAA)

### Program B

```python
1
print-input()
```

[Input A](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/35CroCgzr0Q3M6@gtERD8/9/A4hAHUwEAA)

[Input B](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/35CroCgzr0Q3M6@gtERDE0MAAA)

-2 bytes thanks to [Jiři](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/101306/ji%c5%99%c3%ad)

-9 thanks to [tsh](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/44718/tsh) by changing the version.

Comment: I think you can save 2 bytes by using positive indexes.

Comment: `6\nprint(input()%5)` and `5\nprint(input()%2)` for python 2.

Comment: @tsh Thanks, but I golfed your code(s) by 5 bytes. How did I not think about that???

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), <s>26</s> 24 bytes

#### Program A, 12 bytes

```
\(x)x<"\\(y"
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMEiR9ulpSVpuhZrYjQqNCtslGJiNCqVIEI3NR011GPg4mAZdU0uiGCVZpUdQhCiYcECCA0A)

#### Program B, 12 bytes

```
\(z)z>"\\(y"
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMEiJ9ulpSVpuhZrYjSqNKvslGJiNCqVIEI3NZ001IH8Cs0KG6A4WEZdkwsiCFUMFYRoWLAAQgMA)

Two anonymous functions differing by the name of the variable. We then check whether the function text (essentially the variable name) is smaller or bigger (lexicographically) than the beginning of the function (`\` escaped and `(`) with `y` appended.

Comment: Can you explain this one? I'm not that type of person that is familiar with R.

Comment: @Joao-3 here you go.

Comment: @pajonk - I saw your ```grep``` version on mobile, and thought that something like this could be shorter...  and now when I got to a computer I found you'd beaten me to it!  ...but... now found a [23-byter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/256189/95126)...

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 2x7 = 14 bytes

Both functions return a Boolean value.

A: `s=>s>{}`

B: `S=>S<{}`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/e9oy1Vsa1dsV13L5WT7P9jWLtimuvZ/cn5ecX5Oql5OfrqGo4ajXkl@cElRZl66hqamJheqpBNuSSd8Op3QdP4HAA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 4 bytes

#### Program A, 2 bytes

```
0c
```

#### Program B, 2 bytes

```
1c
```

#### Test cases

- [Program A, Input A](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCIwYyIsIiIsIjBjIl0=)
- [Program A, Input B](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCIwYyIsIiIsIjFjIl0=)
- [Program B, Input A](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCIxYyIsIiIsIjBjIl0=)
- [Program B, Input B](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCIxYyIsIiIsIjFjIl0=)

#### Explanation

`0c` checks whether `0` is in the input, and `1c` checks whether `1` is in the input.

Answer (score 3):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 6 + 6 = 12 bytes

```bash
grep A
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724qjhjwUKNpaUlaboWy9KLUgsUHCGczZp2-impZfp5pTk5XKnJGfkKKvYQmQUo6gA)

```bash
grep B
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724qjhjwUKNpaUlaboWy9KLUgsUnCCczZp2-impZfp5pTk5XKnJGfkKKvYQmQUQdY4QHgA)

Output is via exit code.

Answer (score 3):

## ><>, 10 bytes

```
0"i=n;
```

And

```
1io;
```

[Try it](https://mousetail.github.io/Fish/#eyJ0ZXh0IjoiMFwiaT1uOyIsImlucHV0IjoiMFwiaT0iLCJzdGFjayI6IiIsInN0YWNrX2Zvcm1hdCI6Im51bWJlcnMiLCJpbnB1dF9mb3JtYXQiOiJjaGFycyJ9)

### Explanation

First we push a 0 or a 1. This is useless, but identifies the programs.

Then we push the string `"0=n;0"` (because strings wrap around). This means the `0` or `1` character code will be the last character on the stack.

We get the first character of the output program, and print if they are equal we print 1, otherwise 0.

The second program is similar except we can just print the first character of the first program so we can skip the `=` to save 1 byte.

Answer (score 3):

## [Motorola MC14500B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motorola_MC14500B) Machine Code, 3 bytes

Outputs `0` for truthy and `1` for falsy.

#### Program A, 1.5 bytes

```
118
```

Disassembled:

```
1    ; Read input from the I/O pin into RR.
1    ; Read input from the I/O pin into RR.
8    ; Output RR to the I/O pin.
```

#### Program B, 1.5 bytes

```
428
```

Disassembled:

```
4    ; Read input from the I/O pin and store (RR AND (NOT INPUT)) into RR.
2    ; Read input from the I/O pin and store (NOT INPUT) into RR.
8    ; Output RR to the i/O pin.
```

#### Explanation

Program A outputs the second bit of input, which is 0 for Program A and 1 for Program B.

Program B outputs the complement of the second bit of input, which is 1 for Program A and 0 for Program B.

Answer (score 3):

## Haskell, 21 bytes

##### function A, 11 bytes

`even.length`

##### function B, 10 bytes

`odd.length`

Answer (score 3):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 2 bytes

```
0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/3wCIAA)

```
1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/3xCIAA)

With inspiration from [Neil's Retina answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/256059/85334). Both full programs succeed on themselves and fail on each other. Each program unifies the input (and output) with the single numeric literal in the body, which matches the syntax for providing numbers as input.

Answer (score 2):

## [Brainbool](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 6 bytes

A: `1,.` 
B: `,+.`

[A with A input](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70yqSgxMy8pPz9nwYKlpSVpuhaLDXX0ICyowAKECAA)
[A with B input](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70yqSgxMy8pPz9nwYKlpSVpuhaLDXX0ICyowILFOtpQEQA)
[B with B input](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70yqSgxMy8pPz9nwYKlpSVpuhaLdbT1ICyowAKECAA)
[B with A input](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70yqSgxMy8pPz9nwYKlpSVpuhaLdbT1ICyowILFhjpQEQA)

**A explanation:**

```
1 this is comment used for "1" input
, reads character
. and print it back
```

**B explanation:**

```
, reads character; also it is used as "0" input
+ negates the value
. print the value
```

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL) (both programs), score 4

Program A: `oo`

Program B: `I\`

Each program with itself as input outputs a *truthy* result, specifically a numeric array containing *positive integers*. Each program with the other as input outputs a *falsy* result, specifically a numeric arrray containing *at least a zero entry*. See truthy/falsy [criteria](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/95057/36398) in MATL, or use this truthy/falsy [test](https://tio.run/##bc07DoAgEATQnlNsY2j1BB6EUBB/rFkIYZfCwrNjR/xNPW8mOKFaR3ikA1zBYEiEEwpgTEWs0pKL@EO3UirsQTwysGSMmzrfMwvxovTqiBv7c/bj4nz7n3dO5A5bqxmgtxc).

- [Program A with input A](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/Pz///3/1/Hx1AA)
- [Program A with input B](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/Pz///391zxh1AA)
- [Program B with input A](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/3zPm/3/1/Hx1AA)
- [Program B with input B](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/3zPm/391zxh1AA).

#### How it works

Program A:

```
o  % Implicit input. Convert codepoints to numbers. Gives numeric vector
o  % Modulo 2 of each entry. Implicit display
```

Program B:

```
I  % Push 3
\  % Implicit input. Modulo (3, of code points). Gives numeric vector. Implicit display
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), 34 bytes

#### Program A, 17 bytes

```
A(l)=\{l[2]=65\}
```

#### Program B, 17 bytes

```
B(l)=\{l[2]=66\}
```

Input is a list of character codepoints, and output is `1` for truthy (accepting) and `undefined` for falsey (rejecting).

This is just the first strategy I thought of; there might be better ways out there.

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/hgprnijd4r)

[Try It On Desmos! - Prettified](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/2lekd6ww2b)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>6</s> 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

- -2 thanks to Kevin Cruijssen

#### Program A, <s>3</s> 2 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
0å
```

#### Program B, <s>3</s> 2 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
1å
```

#### Test cases

- [Program A, Input A](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f4PBSMAEA)
- [Program A, Input B](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f4PDS//8NDy8FAA)
- [Program B, Input A](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f8PDS//8NDi8FAA)
- [Program B, Input B](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f8PBSMAEA)

#### Explanation

`0å` checks whether `0` is in the input, and `1å` checks whether `1` is in the input.

Comment: No need for the `.` in either program. `.å` is a non-vectorized contains check (which I haven't used even once thus far I think ). Just `å` does what you want.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen thanks

Answer (score 2):

## Java 19 using exit codes, 146 (73 + 73)

```java
interface A{static void main(String[]a){System.exit(a[1].charAt(0)%65);}}
```

```java
interface B{static void main(String[]a){System.exit(a[1].charAt(0)%66);}}
```

Run it with variations of:

```
cat A.java | xargs java B
echo $?
```

## Java 19 using standard out, 158 (79 + 79) bytes

```java
interface A{static void main(String[]a){System.out.print(a[1].charAt(0)==65);}}
```

```java
interface B{static void main(String[]a){System.out.print(a[1].charAt(0)==66);}}
```

Run it with variations of:

```
cat A.java | xargs java A
```

Comment: Wouldn't using class instead of interface save some bytes?

Comment: Using `class` instead of `interface` saves 8 bytes.

Comment: If you use `class` instead of `interface`, then you need to be explicit about making the main method public. This isn't true for interfaces because all methods on interfaces are public by default. That is, `class A{public` is 2 characters more than `interface A{`.

Answer (score 2):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 7 bytes

Outputs `,` for truthy and `F` for falsy.

#### Program A, 3 bytes

```
,F.
```

#### Program B, 4 bytes

```
F,,.
```

#### Test cases

- [Program A, Input A](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fx00PTAAA)
- [Program A, Input B](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fx03v/383HR09AA)
- [Program B, Input A](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v/fTUdH7/9/HTc9AA)
- [Program B, Input B](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v/fTUdHD0ICAA)

#### Explanation

Program A retrieves and prints the first byte of input, and Program B retrieves and prints the second byte of input. An `F` char (no-op) is inserted into each program in the opposite position of which the program prints out (so that Program A's F is the second char and Program B's F is the first char).

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 11+12 = 23 bytes

**prog a (11 bytes)**

```
scan(,'')>F
```

[prog a with itself as input](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGCpaUlaboWq4uTE_M0dNTVNe3ccInA1AIA) = `TRUE`
[prog a with prog b as input](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGCpaUlaboWq4uTE_M0dNTVNe3cICJrFDGEYIoB) = `FALSE`

**prog b (12 bytes)**

```
!scan(,'')>F
```

[prog a with prog a as input](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGCpaUlaboWaxSLkxPzNHTU1TXt3CBCqzFEYIoB) = `FALSE`
[prog a with itself as input](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGCpaUlaboWaxSLkxPzNHTU1TXt3HAKwVQDAA) = `TRUE`

Answer (score 2):

## x86_32 machine code, 6 bytes

Takes input in ESI (interpreted as a uint8_t *), and outputs to AL `0xAC` for truthy and `0x46` for falsy.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVTfb9owEH73X3FCk2g3AoRWHQJtUve2tz1Waitkxxdw68SZ7bRh2v/Ozk5IQF0figCd78d332f7LLjbHQ6Y7QyM7oXyDq4Wj4ytwe@Ug1fuwFi1VSXXeg8310ApwEsJhZEqVyjBGxBIRUmM5B4t5FxpVW5DKFeUywnu1djn4LtJxN4jNMubDaE5o2uvTMmYwywYMPXYeAb02WojuIaN89x6xqSA8e0Y1lDyAuGiNB5qR/3FHvK6zNb9Slr1QiSoeWVV6QG5U3p/GTT9LKuaysi73PjPIQWdmoCp/YkfuJ4yvooctJFOREuVWUiOtsWOz48jn4@Bi9UbyKFRBG9Ft2mFeQHMmglcD0tREbCVJHMdFpBAZahBK5tby/eAGgssPdPGVC3QGnJTU4Yq0HWOLXraJbO1vBjAOfWSdF4S7gn7kdKe6qICLqVNYsV5g2Od0BOIZ3tPCEka6jrt4UgTILaY06/MsM0TmBuLERedG3AiBpWGsi/LR0LVLEYps5V@Hbadoj2HEzkqHMMgJhzBuZiYELv@j7pTb6i/wyz9@hFqGQ1QNIMR9jguuiCBYzi5Dvqdhos5NaSJoAZ1gVZlND4Q5oC7TKm2UVW7Xbgtx7ZxBM6PNjB0e7d5tcrjyZWiUBpCXprTDQw3r2NAUVHnQ0gOIY1lEGnqrlvXnvoEvQ4yGmZB1zNQa@@@h3mznPe5lalOeT8jVhCuLr0Z0SUx64ufyj8xNnTqxaWdOGxUS6QxttVGf2FYyL/JjET4BvMzJidPkOSex1gnbgU07A@jX@2gwN2km/W7Fdw9jCZUfnuaTnuxAvxdwyeay@ORDujWDPhhhAmdnshJ9xXx2xkj@J6b/Gox5a5grKR/6NeQmNY2kOSoyWJaQu9qg5AUFNqoq@UNY9NZ9DHWvvaj3gN/ISM5iVikZDaNhKSGJBv8aZqkYRVe2MTC2M0uptPL2bx5SGfjw@Ef)

#### Function A, 3 bytes

```
08049001 <a>:
 8049001:   ac                      lodsb
 8049002:   46                      inc esi
 8049003:   c3                      ret
```

#### Function B, 3 bytes

```
08049005 <b>:
 8049005:   46                      inc esi
 8049006:   ac                      lodsb
 8049007:   c3                      ret
```

#### Explanation

Function A copies the first byte of input to AL with `lodsb`. Function B copies the second byte of input to AL by first incrementing ESI before executing `lodsb`.

When Function A is run with itself or Function B is run with itself, the first/second byte (respectively) is copied to AL, which in both cases ends up being `0xAC`.

When Function A is run with B or Function B is run with A, the opposite byte (`0x46`) is copied to AL.

Answer (score 2):

## [Thue](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Thue), 39 + 39 bytes

```
a::=b
b::=~1
c::=:::
A::=d
d::=~0
::=
c
```

[True](https://tio.run/##K8koTf3/P9HKyjaJKwlI1hlyJQMpKysrLkcgncKVAhI04AKSXMn/uYhVCQA) [False](https://tio.run/##K8koTf3/P9HKyjaJKwlI1hlyJQMpKysrLkcgncKVAhI04AKSXMn/uf6DBJ24nCAqnaEqQdpduFwQKp0B)

```
A::=B
B::=~1
C::=:::
a::=D
D::=~0
::=
C
```

[True](https://tio.run/##K8koTf3/39HKytaJywlI1hlyOQMpKysrrkQg7cLlAhI04AKSXM7/uYhVCQA) [False](https://tio.run/##K8koTf3/39HKytaJywlI1hlyOQMpKysrrkQg7cLlAhI04AKSXM7/uf6DBJO4kiAqk6EqQdpTuFIQKpMB)

Has an additional newline (actually two) because of TIO implementation issue.

Truthy = `11` or `1\n1` depending on the implementation, in this case, `1\n1\n`

Falsy = `0`

Answer (score 1):

## POSIX Shell + Utilities, 8+9=17 bytes

```
$ cat ff?; echo; wc -c ff?
cmp $0 -
cmp $0 -
 9 ff1
 8 ff2
17 total
$ ./ff1 < ff1; echo $?
0
$ ./ff1 < ff2; echo $?
1
$ ./ff2 < ff1; echo $?
1
$ ./ff2 < ff2; echo $?
0
```

Some cmp implementations would allow dropping the  `-`, for a score of 6+7=13 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 6 bytes

Program A:

```
№ＳA
```

Program B:

```
№ＳB
```

- [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5//9Ry7T3ezY7whkA) Program A with Program A as input.
- [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5//9Ry7T3ezY7whhOAA) Program A with Program B as input.
- [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5//9Ry7T3ezY7wRiOAA) Program B with Program A as input.
- [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5//9Ry7T3ezY7wRkA) Program B with Program B as input.

Explanation: Each program counts the number of `A`s or `B`s in the input respectively, which will be truthy for itself and falsy for the other program.

Answer (score 1):

## [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), 35 bytes

#### Program A, 17 bytes

```
s/s.*/1/;s/;.*/0/
```

#### Program B, 18 bytes

```
;s/s.*/0/;s/;.*/1/
```

#### Test cases

- [Program A, Input A](https://tio.run/##K05N0U3PK/3/v1i/WE9L31DfuljfGsgw0MciBAA)
- [Program A, Input B](https://tio.run/##K05N0U3PK/3/v1i/WE9L31DfuljfGsgw0P//3xoiZgATM9QHAA)
- [Program B, Input A](https://tio.run/##K05N0U3PK/3/37pYv1hPS99AH8iwBjIM9f//hwgZwoQM9AE)
- [Program B, Input B](https://tio.run/##K05N0U3PK/3/37pYv1hPS99AH8iwBjIM9bGJAQA)

#### Explanation

Program B starts with `;` to distinguish it from Program A.

Program A replaces lines starting with `s` with `1`, and replaces lines starting with `;` with `0`.

Program B replaces lines starting with `s` with `0`, and replaces lines starting with `;` with `1`.

Answer (score 1):

## [gbz80](https://rgbds.gbdev.io/docs/v0.6.0/gbz80.7) [machine code](https://gbdev.io/gb-opcodes/optables/) functions, 8 bytes

(Registers and flags will be referred to in lowercase letters, and the functions in uppercase letters.)

These functions require that the function to test is pointed to by `hl`. Their truthiness is output in the `z` flag: true is a match, false is a non-match.

### Function A, 4 bytes:

```
3e 3e be c9
```

Disassembly:

```
ld a, $3e ; 3e is the opcode of "ld a, d8"
cp [hl]
ret
```

### Function B, 4 bytes:

```
00 af be c9
```

Disassembly:

```
nop
xor a ; set a to 0
cp [hl]
ret
```

We're just checking the first byte of the function using two different ways to set `a` to a constant.

Answer (score 1):

## [PUBERTY](https://esolangs.org/wiki/PUBERTY), 241 bytes

Outputs `0` for truthy and `I` for falsy.

#### Program A, 118 bytes

```
0
It is May 1, 1000, :: PM.q is in his bed, bored.His secret kink is t.Soon the following sounds become audible.oh yes
```

#### Program B, 123 bytes

```
I
0
It is May 1, 1000, :: PM.q is in his bed, bored.His secret kink is t.Soon the following sounds become audible.oh oh yes
```

#### Explanation

Both start with no-ops for simple processing. This answer works in the same way as my [brainfuck](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/256090/92496) answer. Program A prints out the first char of input (not including newlines, which are required for the input to be registered) and Program B prints out the second.

Answer (score 1):

## [GNU sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), 10 bytes

### Program A: 5 bytes

```
/a/q1
```

### Program B: 5 bytes

```
/b/q1
```

Run with `sed -nf <program_filename> <input_filename>` Both programs output [via their exit code](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), where 0 is accepting (or "friend") and 1 is rejecting (or "foe").

By default, `sed` outputs with exit code 0. However, the `q` command in GNU sed can terminate with a different exit code. Program A searches the input text for the letter `a` (which exists in Program A but not Program B). If it's present, then we terminate early with exit code 1. If not, we terminate at the end with the default exit code of 0. Program B does the exact same thing, except that it searches for letter `b` instead of `a`.

Answer (score 1):

## TI-Basic, 8 bytes

#### Program A, 5 bytes

```
6-length(Ans
```

#### Program B, 3 bytes

```
length(Ans
```

Both programs take input from `Ans` as a string. Both output `2` for truthy and `4` for falsy.

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$1\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 0.82 bytes

Port of Lecdi's Jelly answer. Falsy = accepting; Truthy = rejecting.

#### Program A, \$1\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 0.82 bytes

```
!
```

#### Program B, 0 bytes

#### Test cases

- [Program A, Input A](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhYLFSE0lLsAxgcA)
- [Program A, Input B](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhYLFSE0lLtgIReEAQA)
- [Program B, Input A](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhZo1EJFCAMA)
- [Program B, Input B](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhZo1EIuCAMA)

#### Explanation

`!` is the operator for logical `not`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage/wiki/Code-page)

#### Program A, 4 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage/wiki/Code-page)

```
0ŒṘe
```

#### Program B, 4 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage/wiki/Code-page)

```
1ŒṘe
```

#### Test cases

- [Program A, Input A](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/g6KSHO2ek/oezAA)
- [Program A, Input B](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/g6KSHO2ek/v//3xDCAgA)
- [Program B, Input A](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/w6KSHO2ek/v//3wDCAgA)
- [Program B, Input B](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/w6KSHO2ek/oezAA)

#### Explanation

`0ŒṘe` checks whether 0 is in the input, and `1ŒṘe` checks whether 1 is in the input.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 36 bytes

```python
print(''<input())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EQ13dJjOvoLREQ1Pz/38umJitLUwQAA)

```python
print(''==input())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/n6ugKDOvRENd3dY2M6@gtERDU/P/f5iYDUwIAA)

Comment: Do you need two programs?

Comment: @Fmbalbuena What?

Comment: Rollbacked since it's printed

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language)), <s>44</s> 40 bytes

### A, 20 bytes

```
print('['in input())
```

### B, 20 bytes too

```
print(']'in input())
```

[A, when input A](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/v6AoM69EQz1aPTNPITOvoLREQ1MTuygA)

[A, when input B](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/v6AoM69EQz1aPTNPITOvoLREQ1MTLhqLLAoA)

[B, when input A](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/v6AoM69EQz1WPTNPITOvoLREQ1MTLhqNLAoA)

[B, when input B](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/v6AoM69EQz1WPTNPITOvoLREQ1MTuygA)

What I really like about this one, is that you can change 1 character and get the other program.

Answer (score 0):

## [SussyLang](https://github.com/Gabryx64/Sussylang), 88 bytes

Outputs `0` for truthy and `3` for falsy.

#### Program A, 44 bytes

```
pensus
sus 112
sussyballs
imposter
sussybaka
```

#### Program B, 44 bytes

```
sus 115
pensus
sussyballs
imposter
sussybaka
```

#### Test cases

- [Program A, Input A](https://tio.run/##3VdRb9s2EH7nr7gaAyKtthJne9iEuhjWYkCBvhVoH2yjoKSLzJkiVZKK4f6Y/Yz9nv6T9EjJtuLIWfaSBBVgAzre8b7veDzdZdyubjBfaRiJqtbGgXWmcUJa1r0brgpd7d60ZUyiAzRGm8@VLW0K3Bi@hRnMYTF6q9WZAykQnIYK4ROX7sViNKald1CExbXSG6i4GsNWN2fXCBmiAotYCVWCbSxI7lBuO7MPjbVb@JOvOQlgya65IYw8X6dk82UulFuS7z/mSxaWBL1cMFYbnYOwH7kUxTvlImKVemrkIk4h01rCjAE9V9rbCAUXkCSvvEoiUaVhzT/iKlI6RGUulomwb0UpXBTHBw3/GHSNUXDFpUXWE1AssQNjPY/PNTcWTSSFwh6eay2KDg/584uJbTJaji7G8EsMsxkFwkdmMYrvQOur/xonPdLHKP05R5ZXtcTocIDxGM7SszGI@DalcO7iK0bxANW9KBxFwosiOsIRmLYogjLKjtqejd0e02k3o/h7nYtHQF8Im3NTdCxqXUenwWaUgk8O2LpCNy7ZGOEwWvwU/M9bFCtRrpaD8Hmly8Y@e@xJvjL3hV/Kezi8gstHzfZJL2UGQfuCaR2ap4bsqzVPqcI5qozHeb5TyO5TOJDm8BKyQba5wc2PxfTnE0y//fvPj0Q0IqWY6J4T3VPFw5TaPj/O/dJxD/OeGkxguhw67KHAZKeiocrCiPoZVNMd0od9BBy36ycHvfPZR0sJND1yLeDlDKa3WfQ6ot@6juhvNBV/SFv0@6O3Rb4NPUJwaIh8Hg4dkcHCHn2nfT6rpuq1ryGvC6ESg7x4T7ZRnPiV/vXuQtAaPl1H2Pn/j06wRjXEOl@l9KOOvs/3DQlOl7F8NegAKzQlqnxbITqK4O1sof0nl52ZxcPCydDQFLJYLEZ@OvE@vMC/p17Qi9hQtLpIMYJHQeHVG92EfHgx21@BE27bPb40NHtMpnE7g3nvtp2C2tTwg5CP0l@CjIODD5R605gSpJbC@WSxUZhRaIfNymsJun1hH18FOgiETvjITfrXMqON16w/olg/EHWZ5xn4kPQM7sw7Qd/p93pDgn3OtsTaCz@C18l5sJNclYkSFWP0B93wtBPC6/MCr89VIyVj7ex60yYR88VgOr1kh46R7fowtm/ib4KfXBf@dtI82/MJO@n/2vA7)
- [Program A, Input B](https://tio.run/##3Vfvbts2EP/Op7gaAyKtthKnHbAJdTGsxYAC/Vag/WAbASVdZM4UqZJUDPdh9hh7nr1JdpRkm3HkrJ@SoAJsQOT9@f2Ox9Ndxu3qFvOVhpGoam0cWGcaJ6Rl/bvhqtDV7k1bxiQ6QGO0uapsaVPgxvAtzGAOi9F7rc4cSIHgNFQIX7h0LxajMW19gKLdXCu9gYqrMWx1c3aDkCEqsIiVUCXYxoLkDuW2V/vUWLuFP/ia0wIs2Q03hJHn65R0vs6Fckvy/ft8ydotQS8XjNVG5yDsZy5F8UG5iFilnhq5iFPItJYwY0DPtfY6QsEFJMkbL5JIVGm75x9xHSndRmUulomw70UpXBTHBwn/GHSNUXDNpUUWLFAssQdjPY@rmhuLJpJCYYDnRouix0P@/GZim4y2o4sxvIphNqNA@MgsRvE9aKH46zgJSB@j9OccWV7VEqPDAcZjOEvPxiDiu5TacxffMIoHqO6X2qNIeFFERzhaph2KVhhlT23Pxm6P6XTGKP5e5uIR0BfC5twUPYta19FpsBml4JMDtq7QjUs2RjiMFj@1/ucdipUoV8tB@LzSZWOfPfYkX5mHwi/lAxzewOWjZvskSJlB0L5gWofmqSH7as1TqnCOKuNxnu8EsocEDqQ5vIRskG1ucPNjMf35BNN///n7RyIakVBMdM@J7qniYUptnx/nsHQ8wDwQgwlMl0OHPRSY7FQ0VFkYUT@DarpD@n0fAcft@slB73yGaCmBpkeuBbycwfQui6Aj@rXviP5CU/HvaYt@e/S2yLehRwgODZHPw6EjMljYo@@0z2fVVEH72uZ1IVRikBcfSTeKE78TXu8@BJ3i03WEvf//6QRrVEOs81VKP@roQ77vaOF0GctXgw6wQlOiyrcVoqMI3s0Wsj@57NUsHjZOhoamkMViMfLTiffhF/x76heCiA1Fq48UI3gUFF69002bDy9m@ytwwm1n42tDs8dkGnczmPduuymoSw0/CPko/SlIuXXwiVJvGlOC1FI4nyw2amcUsrBZeSlBt6@146tAD4HQCR@5SXgtMzK8ZuGIYv1A1GeeZ@BDEijcm3daeac/6g0t7HO2I9Zd@BG8Tc5bPclVmShRMUZ/0A9Pu0V4e17gzblqpGSsm11vuyRivhhMp5fs0DGyXR/G9k38besn14W/nTTPBj5ht3rbWfqFHQyfNvgf)
- [Program B, Input A](https://tio.run/##3Vddjts2EH7nKSZGgZUSW7veNkArxEHQBAUC5C1A@2AbASXNyowpUiGpNZzD9Bg9T2@yHUqyzXVkN0@7iwiwAZHz833D4Wgm43Z1h/lKw0hUtTYOrDONE9Ky/t1wVehq96YtYxIdoDHafKpsaVPgxvAtzGAOi9E7rS4cSIHgNFQIf3Hpni1GY9p6D0W7uVZ6AxVXY9jq5uIWIUNUYBEroUqwjQXJHcptr/axsXYLv/M1pwVYsltuCCPP1ynpfJkL5Zbk@818ydotQS9XjNVG5yDsn1yK4r1yEbFKPTVyEaeQaS1hxoCeG@11hIIrSJJXXiSRqNJ2zz/iJlK6jcpcLBNh34lSuCiODxL@Megao@CGS4ssWKBYYg/Geh6fam4smkgKhQGeWy2KHg/585uJbTLajq7G8HMMsxkFwkdmMYq/gRaK/xInAeljlP6cI8urWmJ0OMB4DBfpxRhEfJ9Se@7iK0bxANX9UnsUCS@K6AhHy7RD0Qqj7Knt2djtMZ3OGMXfy1w9APpC2JybomdR6zo6DTajFHx0wNYVunHJxgiH0eKn1v@8Q7ES5Wo5CJ9Xumzsk8ee5CtzLvxSnuHwCq4fNNsnQcoMgvYF0zo0jw3ZV2ueUoVzVBmP83wnkJ0TOJDm8AKyQba5wc2PxfT5Cab//vP3j0Q0IqGY6F4S3VPFw5TaPj3OYek4wzwQgwlMl0OHPRSY7FQ0VFkYUT@BarpD@n0fAcft@tFB73yGaCmBpkeuBbyYwfQ@i6Aj@rXviD6jqfj3tEW/PXhb5NvQIwSHhsjn4dARGSzs0Xfa57NqqqB9bfO6ECoxyIsPpBvFid8Jr3cfgk7x8TrC3v//dII1qiHW@SqlH3X0Id@3tHC6jOWrQQdYoSlR5dsK0VEE72cL2Z9c92oWDxsnQ0NTyGKxGPnpxPvwC/499QtBxIai1UeKETwKCq/e6qbNh2ez/RU44baz8aWh2WMyjbsZzHu33RTUpYYfhHyU/hCk3Dr4SKk3jSlBaimcTxYbtTMKWdisvJSg29fa8VWgh0DohI/cJLyWGRles3BEsX4g6jPPM/AhCRS@mXdaeac/6A0t7HO2I9Zd@BG8Ti5bPclVmShRMUZ/0A9Pu0V4fVng7aVqpGSsm13vfBWYTl@yLpnYoWNkuz6M7Zv4u9ZPrgt/O2meDXzCbvXuYIjsXp83@B8)
- [Program B, Input B](https://tio.run/##3VfhjtM4EP7vpxiqkzaBNrsFTuIiik6AkJD4hwQ/2go5yWzqq2MH29mq9zD3GPc89ybLOElbb0n34M/uikitlPGM5/vG48lMxu3qGvOVhpGoam0cWGcaJ6Rl/bvhqtDV7k1bxiQ6QGO0@VLZ0qbAjeFbmMEcFqO3Wp05kALBaagQPnPpHi1GY1p6D0W7uFZ6AxVXY9jq5uwKIUNUYBEroUqwjQXJHcptb/axsXYLr/makwCW7IobwsjzdUo2X@dCuSX5/nO@ZO2SoJcLxmqjcxD2E5eieK9cRKxST41cxClkWkuYMaDnUnsboeACkuSlV0kkqrRd84@4jJRuozIXy0TYt6IULorjg4Z/DLrGKLjk0iILBBRL7MFYz@NLzY1FE0mhMMBzpUXR4yF/fjGxTUbL0cUYnsUwm1EgfGQWo/g7aKH68zgJSB@j9OccWV7VEqPDAcZjOEvPxiDim5Tacxd/YxQPUN2L2qNIeFFERzhaph2KVhllT23Pxm6P6XSbUfy9zsUdoC@Ezbkpeha1rqPTYDNKwXsHbF2hG5dsjHAYLX5r/c87FCtRrpaD8Hmly8Y@eOxJvjK3hV/KWzi8hKd3mu2TIGUGQfuCaR2a@4bsqzVPqcI5qozHeb5TyG5TOJDm8ASyQba5wc2vxfTxCab//fvPr0Q0IqWY6J4T3VPFw5TaPjzOYem4hXmgBhOYLocOeygw2aloqLIwon4A1XSH9Mc@Ao7b9b2D3vkM0VICTY9cC3gyg@lNFkFH9KLviP5CU/EfaYv@uPO2yLehRwgODZHPw6EjMljYo@@0z2fVVEH72uZ1IVRikBcfyDaKE78SXu8@BJ3h/XWEvf//6QRrVEOs81VKP@roQ75vSHC6jOWrQQdYoSlR5dsK0VEEb2YL7T952ptZPCycDA1NIYvFYuSnE@/DC/x76gVBxIai1UeKETwKCq/e6KbNh0ez/RU44bbb42tDs8dkGnczmPduuymoSw0/CPkovRNk3Dr4SKk3jSlBaimcTxYbtTMK7bBZeS1Bt6/dx1eBHgKhEz5yk/BaZrTxmoUjivUDUZ95noEPSWDw3bzT6jv9QW9IsM/Zjlh34UfwKjlv7SRXZaJExRj9QT887YTw6rzAq3PVSMlYN7te@yownf7OumRih46R7fowtm/ir1s/uS787aR5NvAJO@lPbfgN)

#### Explanation

Program A takes the first character and subtracts 112 ('p'); Program B takes 115 ('s') and subtracts the first character.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 6 bytes

**Program A**

```
0
=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f/fgMv2/39DLlsA)

**Program B**

```
1
=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f/fkMv2/38DLlsA)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. If you input `1<` to `1<` it outputs `False`: https://tio.run/##K6gs@f/f0AaEAQ

Answer (score 0):

## C (gcc) and Python 3, <s>31 + 21 = 52</s> 28 + 21 = 49  bytes

*-2 bytes by following [@ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)'s suggestion, and -1 more by using `<'p'` rather than `=='m'` in C.

C:

```
main(){exit(getchar()<'p');}
```

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z83MTNPQ7M6tSKzRCM9tSQ5I7FIQ9NGvUBd07r2//8CAA)

If there's a difference between the first character of input and `'m'`, the program returns `0`; otherwise it returns `1`.

Python 3:

```
print(input()[0]>'m')
```

[Try It Online](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EIzOvoLREQzPaINZOPVdd8/9/AA)

If the ascii code for the first character of input is more than the one for `'m'` (which `p` is but `m` isn't), the program prints `True`; otherwise it prints `False`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 20 bytes

#### Program A, 10 bytes

```python
"$".__gt__
```

#### Program B, 10 bytes

```python
'$'.__lt__
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwao0HYV0BVsFJSWlpaUlaboWW5VUlPTi49NL4uO51FXUgcwcIBMid7MeqEyvuKQos0BDU6-4ICezJCczL7VYQ5OLq6AoM69EI7UsMUcjTROINBWUFdyKMlPzUtCk0iFS-anI4ulwLRji6UhGQZyxYAGEBgA) Link includes all four test cases.

Function which takes a string, returning `True` for friend and `False` for foe.

##### How?

Python string comparison works character by character.

When comparing `$` to `"$".__gt__`, only `$` and `"` are compared. 
Similarly, when comparing `$` to `'$'.__lt__`, only `$` and `'` are compared.

In ASCII values, `" < $ < '`.